# Boundary tracing in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have already seen complex codes for boundary tracing in this site.

I'm a 1st time Matlab user, with a small code with bwtraceboundary.

This code once traced outline of a leaf image( though without tracing the leaf stalk, which was a lighter shade)... before I changed the image size. then all I get out of this, for any image, is a blank.

I thought I'd missed the starting point of the boundary, and tried different values for computing row & col (coords. of start pt.), but none worked.
Can you help me trace the leaf with its stalk please?

The code is:

```
I = imread('C:\...\images3.jpg');
imshow(I)
BW = im2bw(I);
imshow(BW)
dim = size(BW)
col = round(dim(2))-90;
row = min(find(BW(:,col)))
boundary = bwtraceboundary(BW,[row, col],'N');
imshow(I)
hold off;
plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'b','LineWidth',1);
```

Suppose the image matrix is obtained by typing 'I' in command window, will I be able to choose a starting pt.? How?

Comment: @Phonon: it's from the Image Processing toolbox.

Comment: Woops. Didn't know that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you might be missing the starting point (or the direction). If you do

```
imshow(I)
[x, y] = getpts
```

you'll be able to specify the starting point with your mouse. Beware of the [eternal mix-up](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/brcu_al-1.html) between columns and rows when working with images in Matlab!

Comment: @Phonon: It is among the list of [corner cases](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710299/corner-cases-unexpected-and-unusual-matlab)

Comment: The potential mix-up is why I'd always write `[y,x]=getpts`

Comment: thanks for the prompt reply. getpts was what i was looking for. But when i run it, it shows error saying 'Index exceeds matrix dimensions.' Error in ==> dry at 12 `plot(boundary(:,2),boundary(:,1),'b','LineWidth',1);` I read the warning,yet i tried swapping y and x, just to see if it worked. but no. the altered code is `imshow(BW) [x,y]=getpts boundary = bwtraceboundary(BW,[x,y],'E');` direction need not be specified, does it?