# How to get a rectangular subimage from regionprops(Image,'BoundingBox') in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, bounding-box

I have some particles that I've identified in a larger image, and need to parse into smaller images for each particle.  I've used the regionprops 'BoundingBox' function, but haven't been successful yet.  How can I now make a rectangular subimage of image I using BoundingBox?  I can use BoundingBox to draw a rectangle on the original image, but the parameters returned by BoundingBox seem not to be of pixel dimension (x,y, width, height), (x1, y1, x2, y2), etc, which I would expect a bounding box to return.  I've written some sample code using coins.png to make it easier for anyone to understand.   Can you help me with this?  Thanks!

```
figure(1);
I = imread('coins.png');
bw = im2bw(I, graythresh(I));
bw2 = imfill(bw,'holes');
imshow(bw2);


figure(2);
L = bwlabel(bw2);
imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.7 .7 .7]))

figure(3);
imshow(I);
s = regionprops(L, 'BoundingBox');
rectangle('Position', s(1).BoundingBox);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameters returned by regionprops are `[y,x,width,height]` in *matrix* coordinates (see also ["unexpected Matlab"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710299/corner-cases-unexpected-and-unusual-matlab/2462898#2462898).

Thus, to extract the rectangle, you write:

```
subImage = I(round(s(1).BoundingBox(2):s(1).BoundingBox(2)+s(1).BoundingBox(4)),...
       round(s(1).BoundingBox(1):s(1).BoundingBox(1)+s(1).BoundingBox(3)));
```

Comment: Yup, and you can loop over `s.NumObjects`, the iterator replacing Jonas' `1`.

Answer (score 13):

According to the documentation of [REGIONPROPS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/regionprops.html#bqkf8hf):

> `BoundingBox` is `[ul_corner width]`, where:
>
> - **ul_corner**: is in the form `[x y z ...]` and specifies the upper-left corner of the bounding box
> - **width**: is in the form `[x_width y_width ...]` and specifies the width of the bounding box along each dimension

Now you can use [IMCROP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/ref/imcrop.html) functions as `imcrop(I, rect)` where:

> **rect** is a four-element position vector `[xmin ymin width height]` that specifies the size and position of the crop rectangle.

Thus:

```
s = regionprops(L, 'BoundingBox');

subImage = imcrop(I, s(1).BoundingBox);
imshow(subImage)
```

Comment: I didn't know about this use of `imcrop`, its much more readable than directly indexing the image.  FWIW, the docs say `imcrop` rounds the same as Jonas does in the his answer.

Comment: @reve_etrange: it is important to understand the different methods of expressing image location: http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/images/brcu_al-1.html

Comment: The above link changed to: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/image-coordinate-systems.html . Also Image Processing Toolbox introduced new spatial referencing classes: `imref2d` and `imref3d`