# To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change

Tags: matlab

With the following code I get the error message *To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change*.

```
[Ilabel, num] = bwlabel(Ifill);
disp(num);
Iprops = regionprops(Ilabel);
Ibox = [Iprops.BoundingBox]; 
Ibox = reshape(Ibox,[4,50]);%Error using reshape .
imshow(Ibox)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

The error message is pretty self-explanatory.

What you try to reshape doesn't have 4*50 elements (can be more or less). Check the size of Ibox and select the new dimensions such as the number of elements in Ibox doesn't change.

As a side comment, regionprops returns a struct, so even if you reshape it right the imshow will fail as it wants a matrix.
If you want to display the bounding boxes I suggest you to read this previous question:

[How to get a rectangular subimage from regionprops(Image,'BoundingBox') in Matlab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940047/how-to-get-a-rectangular-subimage-from-regionpropsimage-boundingbox-in-matla)