# how to set many arrays value at the same time?

Tags: matlab

I need to check in an array all cells with a value under 9. I build an array with the indexes of those cells using find.

So I have for example array of values

```
A = [ 2, 10, 3 ]
```

and array of index

```
B = [ 1, 3 ]
```

then I need to set in a new C array the value of index 1 and 3 to 7. How can I do this **without** a loop?

Comment: There's so many duplicates around that Im too lazy to even search

Comment: Seems like a job for logical indexing although your last step is kind of unclear. Do you want to set different values at each index, or the same one?

Comment: same one to all those index

Comment: @Adriaan what keyword should I use? I don't mind searching except so far I got nothing.

Comment: If Im still awake and capable in a few hours I'll go look for it. [matlab] [array]  tags seem like a good start

Comment: At the very least, read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to replace values at certain indices.

```
C = ones(7,1);
C( [1 3 4 5 6 7] ) = [1 2 3 4 5 6]
```

Comment: That seems rather inefficient. What if you have a hundred, a thousand, a million indices?