# How to display a string in a certain format

Tags: matlab, formatting, format, string-formatting

I'm writing a program that outputs a specific row of a matrix to the command window. However, I need to display it in a specific format as shown in the following:

Row: `[2 4 6 8 10]`

It should display the following:

```
1 (2%)

2 (4%)

3 (6%)

4 (8%)

5 (10%)
```

rather than just the answers in the command prompt as usual. Does anyone know of a way to do this in MATLAB? Thank you very much. Again, I have the calculation correct, I just don't know what tool to use to format it in the above way.

Answer (score 1):

```
rowc = [2 4 6 8 10];
A = [1:numel(rowc);rowc];
str = sprintf('%d (%d%%) \n',A);
disp(str)
1 (2%) 
2 (4%) 
3 (6%) 
4 (8%) 
5 (10%)
```

[`sprintf`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) let's you create a string in whatever format you want, check the docs for specifics on number caption and special characters.

Apparently the behaviour of `sprintf` is inherited from C, thus it will access any variables you insert in it as a long single column-vector (i.e. `A(:)`, this is called [linear indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)). Meaning that whether you enter two row vectors or two column vectors this code will not work. So you *should* create your input as a correct matrix considering linear indices, hence the extra line to declare `A`.

Comment: `sprintf` is correct but this doesn't produce the correct output for the OP's problem.

Comment: Yours outputs incorrect leading integers. They should be 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 but you have 1, 3, 5, 4, 8.

Comment: @IKavanagh I just spent 10 minutes debugging that thing. Which idiot decided that `sprintf` takes variables as linear indices instead of like the first element of each vector, then the second of each etc...

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`arrayfun`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) to loop through each element in the array and then use [`sprintf`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sprintf.html) to format it correctly. The formatting you need specifically is

```
sprintf('%d (%d%%)\n\n', x, y)
```

where `x` is the leading value and `y` is the value inside the brackets. Then using `arrayfun` we have

```
>> cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x, y) sprintf('%d (%d%%)\n\n', x, y), 1:numel(rowc), rowc, 'UniformOutput', false))
ans =

1 (2%)

2 (4%)

3 (6%)

4 (8%)

5 (10%)
```

where `rowc = [2 4 6 8 10];`.

Another, simpler method with a single input function if the leading values should be divided by `2`

```
>> cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) sprintf('%d (%d%%)\n\n', x / 2, x), rowc, 'UniformOutput', false))
ans =

1 (2%)

2 (4%)

3 (6%)

4 (8%)

5 (10%)
```

**Note**: When `arrayfun` is used with `'UniformOutput', false` the output is a cell array which we can then convert into a matrix of strings using [`cell2mat`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html).