# Can anyone explain to me what is going on in this line of MatLAB code

Tags: matlab, logical-operators, inverse

```
y = rand(20,3); 
aa= unidrnd(2,20,3) - 1;
val = ( aa & y<1.366e-04) | (~aa & y<8.298e-04);
aa(val) = ~aa(val);
```

I have this code.
Can any one explain to me what is happening here. I have tried to understand it step by step (debugging) but I cannot understand the purpose of using inverse '~' in line 4 and also using 'val' as indices.

Comment: I assume you did not write this code yourself since you asked this question, thus I suggest you ask the one that actually did write it to explain you their code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
y = rand(20,3);
```

Creates a matrix of uniformly distributed random numbers, `y`.

```
aa= unidrnd(2,20,3) - 1;
```

Creates a matrix of uniformly distributed random integers, that goes from 1 to 2, and then subtract one. Thus, `aa` is a matrix of 0s and 1s.

```
val = ( aa & y<1.366e-04) | (~aa & y<8.298e-04);
```

This line checks all the values where `aa` is 1AND `y<1.366e-04` OR aa is 0 AND `y<8.298e-04`. Note that this barely happens, being `y` uniformly distributed numbers from 0 to 1, being them this smalls is unlikely.

```
aa(val) = ~aa(val);
```

Take all those cases computed before, and make `aa` change from 0 to 1 or from 1 to 0 if it happened in that index.

Comment: So that means, 'aa' will remain as 'aa' since  `y<1.366e-04` and `y<8.298e-04` will never be satisfied.

Comment: @nashynash Yes, but careful, they can be satisfied. There is a probability of `p=8.298e-04`  of one of them to be satisfied.

Comment: okay.

I have one more doubt as to how MatLAB takes the values of `aa(val) = ~aa(val);`. I tried looking for documentation on this method of assignment but I cannot find it.

Comment: @nashynash ? That is standard Matlab indexing.... Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Comment: okay I will read that. 

I forgot to mention that `'val'` elements are always `'0'`  since the conditions are never satisfied. What does that imply to the assignment in line 4.

Comment: @nashynash Read logical indexing from the post I gave you. Or try `~aa(val)` by yourself