# Logical indexing: What is going on here?

Tags: matlab, matrix-indexing

I have  read [this](http://in.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html) documentation on logical indexing, but it doesn't clarify my problem.
I have this line of code:
`y = rand(20,3); 
aa= unidrnd(2,20,3) - 1;
val = ( aa & y<1.366e-04) | (~aa & y<8.298e-04);
aa(val) = ~aa(val);`
I cannot understand what is going on in the last line  `aa(val) = ~aa(val);`. 
A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077249/can-anyone-explain-to-me-what-is-going-on-in-this-line-of-matlab-code)  but it does not answer the question to the logical indexing specifically or what the logical values were implying.
when the code is run, `val's` elements are zeroes.
Here's the tricky part, if I run only `aa(val)` or `~aa(val)` I get  `Empty matrix: 0-by-1`. But if I run the entire line  `aa(val) = ~aa(val);`, i get a matrix `aa`(with 0's and 1's, 20x3).
`'~'` is performing the inversion of the values right? That means it should be assigning  a matrix of 1's (20x3). But apparently it is not!!I
Can someone please breakdown to me what is happening in the last line.

Comment: Really, you just asked me that in your previous question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can anyone explain to me what is going on in this line of MatLAB code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33077249/can-anyone-explain-to-me-what-is-going-on-in-this-line-of-matlab-code)

Comment: the question raised here is more specific I believe @AnderBiguri

Comment: I linked you to a posst, and explained it in the comments. The question is a bit different, still, this is just a basic misunderstanding of Matlab indexes, and I did linked you to a question that explained that

Comment: Yes, I read the link you send me. I did get a good amount information from that but it wasn't enough . Anyway I did find more documentation and read them as well, but none of them could clarify my doubts. Hence, this question is more directed as you can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of `val`'s elements are zeros (actually logical `false`s or you would get an error), then indexing `aa` by `val` would return nothing (as you point out). So when you do the whole line

```
aa(val) = ~aa(val)
```

it is essentially assigning the inverse of nothing to nothing and hence it doesn't do anything and should return `aa` unchanged. Remember that the `~` is being applied to `aa(val)` and NOT to `val` itself so it inverts the empty matrix `aa(val)` and then assigns this to the empty matrix `aa(val)`.