# Adding multiple rows in Array

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have an array `A` size of `16X16` and I want to add first 3 rows out of 16 in `A`. What is the most efficient solution in MATLAB?

I tried this code but this is not efficient because I want to extend it for large arrays:

```
filename = 'n1.txt';
B = importdata(filename);
i = 1;
D = B(i,:)+ B(i+1,:)+ B(i+2,:);
```

For example, if I want to extend this for an array of size `256x256` and I want to extract 100 rows and add them, how I will do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A(1:3,:);%// first three rows.
```

This uses the [standard indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) of matrix notation. Check Luis's answer I linked for the full explanation on indices in all forms. For summing things:

```
B = A(1:100,:);%// first 100 rows
C = sum(B,1);%// sum per column
D = sum(B,2);%// sum per row
E = sum(B(:));%// sum all elements, rows and columns, to a single scalar
```

Comment: @ShahFahd I edited your original question because there were many syntax errors and it wouldn't run as is.  I also removed a lot of the superfluous code to get to the root of your problem.  It wasn't me who wrote you the answer.  Adriaan did.