# How can I extract row whose element in 1st column is the maximum?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have following data:
eg1:

```
5.34   -32.82    0.71
7.65   -32.74    0.67
9.89   -32.76    0.69
13.81   -32.74    0.68
17.20   -33.27    0.71
22.83   -33.28    0.61
27.10   -33.40    0.67
29.22   -33.20    0.66
```

Output: Comparing `max(:,1)`, I need to extract `29.22   -33.20    0.66`
Eg2:

```
4.58   -49.98    1.27
5.84   -50.13    1.23
7.33   -50.15    1.24
10.39   -50.18    1.28
13.60   -50.03    1.27
17.73   -50.07    1.34
10.99   -49.90    1.41
10.81   -49.76    1.43
```

Output should be:`17.73   -50.07    1.34`
EDIT:

```
4.58    -49.98  1.27    5.31    -38     1.12
5.84    -50.13  1.23    7.65    -38     1.11
7.33    -50.15  1.24    9.88    -38.01  1.12
10.39   -50.18  1.28    13.78   -38     1.12
13.6    -50.03  1.27    17.2    -38.07  1.13
17.73   -50.07  1.34    22.8    -38.06  1.14
10.99   -49.9   1.41    27.19   -38.06  1.14
10.81   -49.76  1.43    29.29   -38.02  1.13
```

OUTPUT: executing a(a==max(a(:,1)),:) for each consecutive column

```
17.73   -50.07  1.34
29.29   -38.02  1.13
```

Comment: Take a look at the second output of the `max` function...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
A=sortrows(A);
A(end,:)
ans =
   29.2200  -33.2000    0.6600
```

[`sortrows`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sortrows.html) sorts your matrix row-wise, with the maximum element of row one obviously at the end. Therefore, extract the `end`row and you're done.

Even faster without sorting your dataset:

```
A(A==max(A(:,1)),:)
```

This finds the entry in the first column where `A` attains its maximum and uses that as a [logical index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) to extract the full row.

Comment: @HaWa, just in case you didn't see it: I made an edit with an even faster solution.

Comment: Thanks. It did the trick. Just to ask if you know the Edit  part as well?