# MATLAB - get specific index from Time Series Object

Tags: matlab, time-series

I am looking for a simple and fast way to get the index of an entry of a Time Series Object. For example:

```
%ts is a time series object with the following properties:
% Common Properties:
        Name: 'unnamed'
        Time: [70001x1 double]
    TimeInfo: [1x1 tsdata.timemetadata]
        Data: [70001x1 double]
    DataInfo: [1x1 tsdata.datametadata]

%first entry of ts is: 0 (time), 0.0667 (data)    
%second entry of ts is: 0.01 (time), 0.0667 (data)
%adn so on...

%I'm looking for an index i, such that i is the entry at the time 500.00
indexEntry = ts.time(i);
result = indexEntry == 500.00
%and resut should be true
```

Comment: Please add some sample data in the exact (MATLAB syntax) format that you are using. Also, are you looking to match floating point values or integers because `==` is not reliable for finding floats...

Comment: I don't understand your example, using `indexEntry = ts.time(i);` you get the you use the value as an index: `ts.time(indexEntry)`.

Comment: I just revised my question. I hope it is now more clearer.

Comment: Not really, I don't get the meaning of `ts.time(ts.time(i))`, which is effectively what you have written.

Comment: @Daniel That was a mistake. I just revised it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tmp = 1:numel(ts.Time);
index = tmp(ts.time==500); %// 7000-by-1 logical array
```

The time at `Time==500` can be found using [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that).

Following [@Daniel's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33801969/matlab-get-specific-index-from-time-series-object/33803077?noredirect=1#comment55371844_33803077) the following should be faster for single indices:

```
index = find(ts.time==500);
```

Comment: Instead of creating `tmp`, you could use `index = find(ts.time==500);`

Comment: @Daniel Though it's more explicit, `find` does have more overhead than logical indexing. Most of the time it isn't really noticeable but worth considering depending on the application.

Comment: @excaza of course the `tmp` uses up RAM, which might be a problem when trying to find a single number in an array of size `1e8` or so. Then the additional computational requirement of `find` might well be worth it.

Comment: @excaza: I compared both versions and `find` is never slower when you are searching for a single index. For large arrays, the `tmp` version is 20 times slower.

Answer (score 0):

Need to pay attention to the floating point data type.

```
index = find(abs(ts.time-500)<0.00001);
```