# "Logical Indexing with a Smaller Array" in matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

The matlab help page for [matrix indexing](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#bq7ekiy-1) says:

> ### Logical Indexing with a Smaller Array
>
> In most cases, the logical indexing array should have the same number
>   of elements as the array being indexed into, but this is not a
>   requirement. The indexing array may have smaller (but not larger)
>   dimensions:
>
> ```
> A = [1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]
> A =
>      1     2     3
>      4     5     6
>      7     8     9
>
> B = logical([0 1 0; 1 0 1])
> B =
>      0     1     0
>      1     0     1
>
> isequal(numel(A), numel(B))
> ans =
>      0
>
> A(B)
> ans =
>      4
>      7
>      8
> ```

What kind of crazy rule is matlab using here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Comment: I don't understand what your actual question is? What code do you specifically not understand?

Comment: It's kind of explained right after the quote you provided: "MATLAB treats the missing elements of the indexing array as if they were present and set to zero".  I say "kind of" because they omit the fact Matlab switches to linear indexing per the example after the sentence: `C = logical([B(:);0;0;0]);` and `isequal(A(C),A(B)) == true`.

Comment: You can view it as if Matlab is applying an __implicit `find`__: `A(find(B))`. (I'm not saying Matlab internally does that; but functionally it's equivalent). That implicit `find` takes care of the two possibly surprising issues: it linearizes the index array `B`, and it picks the integer indices of the `true` entries (making it unimportant that some `false` entries are missing)

Comment: Right, I hadn't realized it was linearizing the array. What sensible behaviour...

Answer (score 0):

To understand this behavior, it's necessary to understand how matrices are stored in memory. Matlab stores matrices using column major layout. This means the 2d matrix:

```
                       A =   1     2     3
                             4     5     6
                             7     8     9
```

is stored in memory as one dimensional array going down the columns of A:

```
A     = { array  = [1  4  7  2  5  8  3  6  9]  
          n_rows = 3
          n_cols = 3                            }
```

The matrix B:

```
                        B =  0     1     0
                             1     0     1
```

is stored in memory as:

```
B     = { array  = [0  1  1  0  0  1]  
          n_rows = 2
          n_cols = 3                            }
```

Let's put the underlying representations next to eachother:

```
A.array = [1  4  7  2  5  8  3  6  9] 
B.array = [0  1  1  0  0  1]
```

Using logical indexing, A(B) gives you `[4, 7, 8]` If you think a bit deeper, what's causing the unintuitive result is the combination of: (1) Matlab uses column major layout and (2) the number of columns in A and B are different.

Note: I'm using pseudo code here. A.array isn't valid code etc...

Bonus:
You can see what happens when the reshape command is called. The underlying data array doesn't change, just the n_rows and n_cols associated with the data array.