# Fill a zeros matrix with specific numbers of 1

Tags: matlab, matrix

I'm facing a problem. I have a zeros matrix `600x600`. I need to fill this matrix with 1080 `1`s randomly. Any suggestions?

Comment: thought I saw this over at Cody :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Or, use the intrinsic routine `randperm` thusly:

```
A = zeros(600);
A(randperm(600^2,1080)) = 1;
```

Comment: :) Was just about to post the same, this one is definitely simple +1

Comment: @Adriaan: thanks.  I'm working on a machine w'out Matlab at the moment.

Comment: Performance wise currently my answer is fastest, yours second and Patrik's third; if you initialise a sparse matrix instead yours is fastest by far.

Comment: A [`sparse` array](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix) (instead of a full, `zeros` array) is probably a better idea in this scenario, due to the low sparsity (0.3%; as mentioned by Adriaan), which could increase performance in any subsequent computations. Yet if a full matrix must be used, depending on whether this array needs to be re-initialized many times or not, one might resort to ["preallocation using the corner element"](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/preallocation-performance#non-default) or [`nullcopy`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/coder.nullcopy.html).

Comment: Hmmm.. in `R`, where one can specify randoms with or without replacement,  `A = matrix(0,600,600);  A[ sample(1:600^2,1080,replace=FALSE)] = 1;` runs pretty fast. Dunno where the hangup is in your answer.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft the array's small enough that it is fast anyway, but when you increase the size (say 1e4 square) the sparsity helps MATLAB in calculating only things for the desired elements, and not everything else as well. Same with allocating memory for a sparse array or full array, see the docs Dev-iL linked.

Answer (score 3):

```
A = sparse(600,600);               %// set up your matrix
N=1080;                            %// number of desired ones
randindex = randi(600^2,N,1);      %// get random locations for the ones
while numel(unique(randindex)) ~= numel(randindex)
    randindex = randi(600^2,N,1);  %// get new random locations for the ones
end 
A(randindex) = 1;                  %// set the random locations to 1
```

This utilises [`randi`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) to generate `1080` numbers randomly between `1` and `600^2`, i.e. all possible locations in your vectors. The `while` loop is there in case it happens that one of the locations occurs twice, thus ending up with less than 1080 `1`.

The reason you can use a single index in this case for a matrix is because of [linear indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that).

The big performance difference with respect to the other answers is that this initialises a sparse matrix, since `1080/600^2 = 0.3%` is very sparse and will thus be faster. (Thanks to [@Dev-iL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3372061/dev-il))

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it,

```
N = 1080; % Number of ones
M = zeros(600); % Create your matrix
a = rand(600^2,1); % generate a vector of randoms with the same length as the matrix
[~,asort] = sort(a); % Sorting will do uniform scrambling since uniform distribution is used
M(asort(1:N)) = 1; % Replace first N numbers with ones.
```