# Concatenate vectors in a specific, non-serial ordering

Tags: matlab, vector, vectorization

I have vectors `a`,`b` and `c`; vectors `a` and `b` contain integer numbers while vector `c` has binary values as elements: (`0`,`1`).

Vector `a` has length *n* and vector `b` has length *k*. Vector `c` has length *n*+*k*.

I want to concatenate vectors `a` and `b` based on vector `c`.

For example. If `c=[1 0 0 1 0 . . . . ]` then I want to create vector `res=[a(1) b(1) b(2) a(2) b(3) . . . ].`

Is there any way to do so without a `for` loop?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
res = c; %// copy c for the result vector
res(c) = a;
res(~c) = b;
```

using [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)! This works because the number of `0` elements in `c` is exactly equal to the number of elements in `b` and the number of `1` elements equals the number of elements in `a`. Logical operators for indexing thanks to [@Dan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34764213/concatenate-vectors-in-a-specific-non-serial-ordering#comment57274724_34764374)

Comment: This is the simplest way to do it by far.

Comment: if `c` is a logical matrix to begin with you can even just do `res(c) = a` and `res(~c) = b`.