# finding the location of max and min and replacing their values in a matrix

Tags: matlab

If I generated a random 5-by-5 matrix using the code `r = rand(5)`.
I would like to find the location of the max value and replace this value by `10`, and the min value and replace the value by `-10`.

How can I do it?

i tried to do the following:

```
r=rand(5)
find(max(max(r)))
```

Will this line give me the correct location of max value? And if it was correct now how can I replace the value by `10`?

Answer (score 2):

```
r = rand(5);
maxr = max(r(:));%//get maximum
r(r==maxr) = 10; %// replace maximum with 10
```

Use [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) to replace the maximum value with `10`.

Comment: Well done handling multiple occurrences of the maximum

Answer (score 2):

`max` returns two output arguments, first the value and then the index. Using `(:)` to convert your matrix to a vector and linear indexing to access, you can use this code:

```
[value,index]=max(r(:));
r(index)=10;
```