# What does A(input) do in the most general input?

Tags: matlab

I was working with simple matrix and got something weird.

```
A = 
2 3 
5 6 
8 9
```

And I did this.

```
A([1 3],[1 2 2]) 

ans = 
2 3 3 
8 9 9
```

And I did this.

```
A([1 3],[1 2]) 

ans = 
2 3 
8 9
```

I can't figure out why MatLab is having that result.

Or, more generally, what does A(input) do in the most general input?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`A(input)` generates matrices from the indices that are passed by `input`. Simple example would be

```
A(1,1) # select the element from first row, first column
A(2,:) # select the complete second row
A(:,2) # select the complete second column
A([1 2],1) # select the element from the first and second row and first column each
```

From your example

```
A([1 3],[1 2 2]) # Select elements from first row and first and two times second column 
                 #as well as third row with first and two times second column.
```

Similar

```
A([1 3],[1 2])  # Select elements from first row and first and second column
                # as well as third row and first and second column
```