# How do I extract the odd and even rows of my matrix into two separate matrices in scilab?

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, scilab

I'm very new to scilab syntax and can't seem to find a way to extract the even and odd elements of a matrix into two separate matrix, suppose there's a matrix `a`:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

How do I make two other matrix `b` and `c` which will be like
`b=[2 4 6 8]` and `c=[1 3 5 7 9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
b = a(mod(a,2)==0);
c = a(mod(a,2)==1);

b =
     2     4     6     8
c =
     1     3     5     7     9
```

Use [`mod`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mod.html) to check whether the number is divisible by 2 or not (i.e. is it even) and use that as a [logical index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) into `a`.

Comment: Thanks! that worked, except its `modulo` in scilab instead of mod.

Answer (score 3):

You can separate the matrix by calling row and column indices:

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
b=a(2:2:end);
c=a(1:2:end);
```

`[2:2:end]` means `[2,4,6,...length(a)]` and `[1:2:end]=[1,3,5,...length(a)]`. So you can use this tip for every matrix for example if you have a matrix `a=[5,4,3,2,1]` and you want to obtain the first three elements:

```
a=[5,4,3,2,1];
b=a(1:1:3)
b=
   1  2  3 
% OR YOU CAN USE
b=a(1:3)
```

If you need elements 3 to 5:

```
a=[5,4,3,2,1];
b=a(3:5)
b=
   3  2  1
```

if you want to elements 5 to 1, i.e. in reverse:

```
a=[5,4,3,2,1];
b=a(5:-1:1);
b=
  1  2  3  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

The title is about selecting rows of a matrix, while the body of the question is about elements of a vector ...
With Scilab, for rows just do

```
a = [1,2,3 ; 4,5,6 ; 7,8,9];
odd = a(1:2:$, :);
even = a(2:2:$, :);
```

Example:

```
--> a  = [
  5  4  6
  3  6  5
  3  5  4
  7  0  7
  8  7  2 ];

--> a(1:2:$, :)
 ans  =
  5  4  6
  3  5  4
  8  7  2

--> a(2:2:$, :)
 ans  =
  3  6  5
  7  0  7
```