# Is there a built-in function that extracts values unequal to zero in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, built-in

I was wondering if there is a function like the one (smaller) below, but instead extracts values that are unequal to zero?

```
a = [67 0 8 25 0 20 0 90 7 2 9];

smaller10 = a(a < 10)

smaller10 =

 0     8     0     0     7     2     9
```

Comment: What's the programming language? Looks like matlab or octave. I can answer your question if it is one of those, but you have to provide that information.

Comment: Of course, I'm sorry. It's MATLAB ;)

Comment: All you wanted to know about indexing in Matlab: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Answer (score 3):

Either use

```
a(a~=0)
```

or

```
nonzeros(a).'
```

You can find the documentation for `nonzeros` [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html).

Comment: I'd use `.'` instead of `'` in case values are complex. And Matlab requires `~` instead of `!`

Comment: I'd rather use `a(logical(a))` - should be faster.