# Index of maximum value element in each row (last index)

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, max

I need to find index of maximum element in each row in matrix in MATLAB.
Something like

```
[~,indexes] = maxValues = max(p_y_x,[],2);
```

works fine, but I need to get LAST index (when there is more than one with maximum value).
Now I have something like this:

```
N=size(p_y_x,1);
maxValues = max(p_y_x,[],2);
indexes=zeros(1,N);

for n=1:N
   indexes(n)=find(p_y_x(n,:)==maxValues(n),1,'last');
end
```

Which is complicated and not very efficient (because of the `for` loop).

I doubt something that trivial must be done that way. Is there a more optimal solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same code for finding the first occurrence works for the last if you flip the array horizontally and then correct the indices:

```
[~, indexes] = max(fliplr(p_y_x),[],2);
indexes = size(p_y_x,2)-indexes+1;
```

Comment: Do note that this is the fastest option, by far. By my timings My answer's as fast as the original (surprisingly enough), @Divakar's is 35% faster, this one is a whole 70% faster.

Comment: @Adriaan Thanks for the timing!

Comment: Yes, this indeed is the fastest solution.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [linear indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) to get the last index of the maximum by finding all maximum values within a row, then using the index of the last to index the original column:

```
N=size(p_y_x,1);

for n=1:N
   [~, indices(n)] = max(fliplr(p_y_x(n,:))); %// find maxima in a row
end
indices= size(p_y_x,2)-indices+1;
```

Since the new execution engine was introduced in MATLAB R2015b `for` loops are no longer very slow, and this is the intuitive way of doing this. Omitting the time consuming `find` will probably be the largest efficiency improvement you can make.

Note that I renamed `indexes` to `indices`, as that is the Latin plural.

Answer (score 4):

Let [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) help you out -

```
[r,c] = find(bsxfun(@eq,p_y_x,max(p_y_x,[],2)))
indexes = accumarray(r,c,[],@max)
```

If you are a fan of `one-liners`, for fun you could also do -

```
[~,indexes] = max(cumsum(bsxfun(@eq,p_y_x,max(p_y_x,[],2)),2),[],2)
```