# Randomly add numbers to a N x M zero matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, random, sparse-matrix

I wanted to know how I can go about randomly placing numbers (up to 10 numbers) in a matrix.  The numbers will range from 1 to 10.

I am starting with `A = zeros(5,8)`, then randomly place the 10 random numbers around the matrix.

Example of matrix:

[image]

Comment: Anywhere between 0 to10 random numbers, or exactly 10? How are the random numbers distributed?

Comment: `A = randi(10, [5 8])` ?

Comment: @Amro, thanks for your help!.  the numbers are randomly distributed, and I wanted to replace exactly 10 zeros.  This is just a sample test, as my matrix will be much larger (1024, N), where N is variable, and the number of non-zero entries will be 20.   I am eventually trying to create a 20-Sparse matrix.  Thanks.

Comment: @Joe use the `randperm` method, in that case `Idx = randperm(1024*N,20)`

Comment: @Adriaan, thanks for your input.  When I use the command, `tmp = randperm(1:10*5)`, I get the error, `Size inputs must be scalar`.

Comment: `sprand`? your question is still not clear.. Edit and describe exactly what you're trying to do, an example would be nice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
N=20;                            %// number of columns
M=1024;                          %// number of rows
NumRand = 20;                    %// number of random numbers
RandomScalars = rand(NumRand,1); %// random numbers
MyMatrix= sparse(M,N);           %// initialise matrix   
Idx = randperm(M*N,NumRand);     %// get indices to be filled
MyMatrix(Idx) = RandomScalars;   %// fill indexed places
```

Basically you use [`randperm`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html) to create a certain number of [linear indices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) to index your matrix. Simply place the desired numbers there and you're done.