# How to convert RGB to NV12 color space using IPP

Tags: c, rgb, yuv, intel-ipp, nv12-nv21

Video encoders like Intel® Media SDK require NV12 video input format.

[NV12 format](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php#NV12) is YUV 4:2:0 format ordered in memory with a Y plane first, followed by packed chroma samples in interleaved UV plane.

Example:
`YYYYYY`
`YYYYYY`
`UVUVUV`

[image]

RGB color format, refers to Pixel-Order RGB (byte per pixel, lower byte is Red):
`RGBRGBRGBRGBRGB`
`RGBRGBRGBRGBRGB`

[image]

I did some Web research, and found out that regarding NV12, [YUV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV) is defined as YCbCr color space.
There are currently at least 2 possible YCbCr formats apply NV12:

- [BT.601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._601) - Applies SDTV
- [BT.709](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rec._709) - Applies HDTV

My question is: **Is there as [IPP](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-ipp) function that converts RGB color space to NV12?**

Comment: @Rotem: please clarify whether you're looking for matlab answers, and if not, please make another edit to change the last sentence I added.  (And remove the `[matlab]` tag)

Comment: Should I split the question into 3 different questions: 1. Using IPP, 2. Pain C Code, 3. SSE optimized code?

Comment: If you wrote a highly specialised toolbox, GitHub is probably the better place for that. Self-Q/A works on Stack Overflow only if your question is on-topic. Yours are, as evident by the closure, much too broad. Either try and write it as a narrow-shaped question with properly explained answer (as opposed to a pure code dump) or create a GitHub page with your toolbox.

Comment: See it like this: you made one of the world's finest bicycles. If you want to promote it, a car show would be a bad place. Both are transportation vehicles, but of different kinds. For a great example of how a self-Q/A should look like on Stack Overflow I recommend you take a look at this one:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Comment: OK, I gave the focus for the IPP solution.

Comment: Looks like a decent self-answered question now - voting to re-open.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I found out that IPP function exists:

[ippiRGBToYCbCr420_8u_C3P2R](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/503959)

It was hard to find, because the function name or description does not mention NV12.
The function uses BT.601 standard.

Here is a code sample for converting **RGB** to **NV12** in **BT.601** standard:

```
void Rgb2NV12(const unsigned char I[], int image_width, int image_height, unsigned char J[])
{
    IppStatus ipp_status;
    int srcStep = image_width*3;
    int dstYStep = image_width;
    int dstCbCrStep = image_width;
    IppiSize roiSize = {image_width, image_height};

    const Ipp8u* pSrc = (Ipp8u*)I;

    Ipp8u *pDstY    = (Ipp8u*)J;                            //Y color plane is the first image_width*image_height pixels of J.
    Ipp8u *pDstCbCr = (Ipp8u*)&J[image_width*image_height]; //In NV12 format, UV plane starts below Y.

    ipp_status = ippiRGBToYCbCr420_8u_C3P2R(pSrc, srcStep, pDstY, dstYStep, pDstCbCr, dstCbCrStep, roiSize);

    //if (ipp_status != ippStsNoErr), Handle errors...          
}
```

---

---

---

**Converting RGB to NV12 with BT.709 standard:**

As for 2019, BT.709 (HDTV) standard is probably more relevant than BT.601 (SDTV).

IPP lacks a function for direct conversion from RGB to NV12 in BT.709 standard.
There is a function that converts **BGR** to **NV12**.
The solution includes two stages:

1. Convert from **RGB** to **BGR** (swap channels).
   Code sample uses [`ippiSwapChannels_8u_C3R`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-swapchannels) for **RGB** to **BGR** conversion.
2. Convert from **BGR** to **NV12**.
   Code sample uses [`ippiBGRToYCbCr420_709CSC_8u_C3P2R`](https://software.intel.com/en-us/ipp-dev-reference-bgrtoycbcr420-709csc) for **BGR** to **NV12** conversion.

The sample function requires some extra memory space for storing the intermediate BGR image.
A pointer to the sketch memory is passed to the function (the memory should be allocated outside the function).

Here is a code sample for converting **RGB** to **NV12** in **BT.709** standard:

```
//sketch_buff - Temporary buffer for storing image in BGR format.
//              Size of sketch_buff must be at least image_width*image_height*3 bytes.
void Rgb2NV12_709(const unsigned char I[],
                  const int image_width, 
                  const int image_height,
                  unsigned char sketch_buff[],
                  unsigned char J[])
{
    IppStatus ipp_status;    
    int srcStep = image_width*3;
    int dstBgrStep = image_width*3;
    int dstYStep = image_width;
    int dstCbCrStep = image_width;
    IppiSize roiSize = {image_width, image_height};

    const Ipp8u* pRGB = (Ipp8u*)I;
    Ipp8u* pBGR = (Ipp8u*)sketch_buff; //BGR image is stored in sketch_buff
    Ipp8u *pDstY    = (Ipp8u*)J;                            //Y color plane is the first image_width*image_height pixels of J.
    Ipp8u *pDstCbCr = (Ipp8u*)&J[image_width*image_height]; //In NV12 format, UV plane starts below Y.

    const int bgrOrder[3] = {2, 1, 0};

    //Swap Red and Blue color channels - convert from RGB to BGR
    //Store the result into sketch_buff (sketch buffer is allocated outside the function)
    ipp_status = ippiSwapChannels_8u_C3R(pRGB, srcStep, pBGR, dstBgrStep, roiSize, bgrOrder);

    //if (ipp_status != ippStsNoErr), Handle errors...

    //Convert BGR to NV12 in BT.709 standard
    ipp_status = ippiBGRToYCbCr420_709CSC_8u_C3P2R(pBGR, srcStep, pDstY, dstYStep, pDstCbCr, dstCbCrStep, roiSize);

    //if (ipp_status != ippStsNoErr), Handle errors...
}
```

Comment: My optimized implementation in C (vectorized using SSE intrinsics) can be found here: [https://github.com/cohenrotem/Rgb2NV12](https://github.com/cohenrotem/Rgb2NV12).