# yuv420 interleaved to not interleaved, or directly png

Tags: ffmpeg, yuv

I have an image file `myImage.yuv` with UV planes interleaved and I want to convert it into `png`.

I'm using:

```
ffmpeg -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1944x1204 -i myImage.yuv output.png
```

This would be OK if the image wasn't interleaved, how can I specify this to ffmpeg?

Comment: UV planes interleaved? Do you mean [NV12](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XboNY.png) pixel format? `ffmpeg -pixel_format nv12 -video_size 1944x1204 -i myImage.yuv output.png`

Comment: @Rotem exactly, this solved it. Maybe you can post it like an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UV planes interleaved applies NV12 pixels format.

We may use the following command for converting raw NV12 file to PNG image:

```
ffmpeg -pixel_format nv12 -video_size 1944x1204 -i myImage.yuv output.png
```

---

NV12 format is YUV420 pixel format ordered in semi-planar format, where the Y channel is in one plane, and the interleaved UV elements are in a second plane.

The following diagram demonstrates the NV12 format:
[image]

Note: I created the diagram back in 2016, for the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768751/how-to-convert-rgb-to-nv12-color-space-using-ipp) (the post has few more details about the NV12 format).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`swapuv` filter](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#swapuv)

```
ffmpeg -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1944x1204 -i myImage.yuv \
       -vf swapuv output.png
```

Comment: This changes the output, but not in the right way. My image is organized as First all `Y` and then `U`and `V` values "interleaved" . Not sure This was clear in my question

Comment: Doh, sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. See if `swapuv` does the job