# Trying to check if array is always increasing

Tags: arrays, matlab, sorting

Say I have an array `A = [ 1 3 4 6 7 8]` and another array of the same size `S = [1 1 0 1 0 1]`.

I need to check if `A(i)+S(i)` is greater than or equal to `A(i-1)+S(i-1)`, for the entire length of the array. In other words I'm checking if `A + S` is monotonically increasing.

However, if `S(i-1)` is zero, then I want to compare `A(i)+S(i)` to `A(i-2)+S(i-2)` instead.

Simply speaking, I need to check if all the elements in `A+S` are monotonically increasing, ignoring the ones with `S=0`.

Comment: ok.....so what is the question?

Comment: As soon as [`diff`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diff.html) goes negative it's no longer increasing. Use [logical indexing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) to remove the `S=0` elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
isequal(sort(A(S)),A(S)) % or isequal(sort(A(S==1)),A(S==1))
```

Or if `S` is not a logical matrix, i.e. can have values other than `1` and `0`

```
idx = S ~= 0;
isequal(sort(A(idx)),A(idx))
```

Adriaan's suggestion should be faster, especially on large matrices

```
all(diff(A(S~=0)) >= 0) % or replace >= with > if you want it to be strictly increasing
```