# Iterate over diagonal elements of a Matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, diagonal

I need to get the indexes of all diagonals in a matrix.  The matrix can be non square.

The `diag` function gives the values, but I need the coords. So for instance with this: `[1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]`, I want `[1 1; 2 2; 3;3]` PLUS `[2 6]` and `3` because they are the upper diagonals of the matrix, and same for below i.e. `[4 8]` and `7`.  So the full list of indexes is:  `[1 1; 2 2; 3 3], [1 2; 2 3], [1 3], [2 1], [3 2], [3 1]`.

And I need this in the other diagonal direction too...

And it needs to work for matrices of any shape i.e. not just square ones, including vectors (i.e. 1xn and nx1) - but I guess I can test for these last 2 cases and treat separately.

EDIT:
An example of a non square matrix is this 3x2 one:

```
1   2
3   4
5   6
```

In this case, the indexes I need are:

```
[1 1; 2 2]
[2 1; 3 2]
[1 2]
[3 1]
```

And then the same for diagonals running the other way...

I am aware of the `diag` function and can write a bit of code to iterate over the matrices, but I can't then see how to easily turn those values into indexes.

As for why I need this: It's an online course I'm doing in MatLab. An introduction to programming, using MatLab. I'm a reasonably experienced programmer but I'm not familiar with MatLab and I want to learn it more.

The question asks us to find the biggest product of any `n` numbers in any direction, i.e. rows, cols, and diagonals (both ways).  And the thing is we don't return the product, we return the indexes of the elements making up this product.

I hope this provides more information.

EDIT 2:
Sorry for not getting back to you guys, I've been very busy doing other things.  When I first posted here, I assumed I was missing something and this would be something that took a few lines.  But it's trickier than that, so the code you guys are posting will take me a little more time to go through and understand etc.  But I hope to do this today and accept one as an answer.  Thanks for all the replies.

Comment: What should be the shape of the output? does your `alt_diag` gets also the position of the diagonal (-2,-1,0,1,2)? Can you provide an example (input and output) with a non-square matrix?

Comment: What are you going to do with these indices? Do you need the indices themselves, or do you need to get the values and perform some operations on them? If the latter, you can use `diag` to retrieve the values of any of the diagonals, even on non-square matrices.

Comment: Ok, so the shape of the output needs to be a list of these indexes.  So for the above 2x2 matrix, the indexes are actually: [1 1; 2 2; 3 3], [1 2; 2 3], [1 3], [2 1], [3 2], [3 1].  I've updated the question above.

Comment: Since it is homework I will not provide the full answer, but you should be able to define the diagonals `M(i,i)` and then use linear indexing to move them. Then either convert by hand (which is easy) to (i,j) indices or use `sub2ind`. This should be simple if you use linear indexing. Moving the diagonal to the right is the same as `idxArray = idxArray+size(M,1)`. Moving the diagonal down would only be `idxArray=idxArray+1`. Just remember the diagonal may get shorter...

Comment: @davo36 Regarding your edit, don't worry about it. Take your time, understand the problem and solutions, and get back to us if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I coded this up myself last night.  It's very long and I'm sure it can be done in better ways.  I don't know MatLab well, so my solution is pretty naive.  But it works.

```
function indicies = maxproduct(A, n)


function diagIndicies = getAllReverseDiagonalIndicies()
    % This function returns lists of indicies in the reverse diagonal direction (top-right to bottom-left)
    if rows == 1 
        numCells = 0;
        for j=1:length(A)
            temp = [1, j];
            numCells = numCells + 1;
            diagIndicies{numCells} = temp;
        end
        return
    end

    % This loop adds all diagonals down and to the right, to the end of the matrix.
    %fprintf('Diagonals down to main one are:\n');
    numCells = 0;
    for x=1:rows
        rowNum = x;
        colNum = 1;
        temp = [];
        while rowNum >= 1 && rowNum <= rows && colNum <= cols
            temp = [temp; [rowNum colNum]];
            rowNum = rowNum - 1;
            colNum = colNum + 1;
        end
        numCells = numCells + 1;
        temp = flipud(temp); % Need row major order for assignment
        %disp(temp);
        diagIndicies{numCells} = temp;
    end

    % Now go along bottom row
    %fprintf('Diagonals along bottom are:\n');
    for y=2:cols
        rowNum = rows;
        colNum = y;
        temp = [];
        while rowNum >= 1 && colNum <= cols
            temp = [temp; [rowNum colNum]];
            rowNum = rowNum - 1;
            colNum = colNum + 1;
        end
        numCells = numCells + 1;
        temp = flipud(temp); % Need row major order for assignment
        %disp(temp);
        diagIndicies{numCells} = temp;
    end                

end

function diagIndicies = getAllDiagonalIndicies()
    % This function returns lists of indicies in the main diagonal direction (top-left to bottom-right)
    if rows == 1 
        numCells = 0;
        for j=1:length(A)
            temp = [1, j];
            numCells = numCells + 1;
            diagIndicies{numCells} = temp;
        end
        return
    end

     % This loop adds all diagonals down and to the left, to the lhs of the matrix.
    %fprintf('Diagonals down to main one are:\n');
    numCells = 0;
    for x=1:rows
        rowNum = x;
        colNum = cols;
        temp = [];
        while rowNum >= 1 && rowNum <= rows && colNum >= 1
            temp = [temp; [rowNum colNum]];
            rowNum = rowNum - 1;
            colNum = colNum - 1;
        end
        numCells = numCells + 1;
        temp = flipud(temp); % Need row major order for assignment
        %disp(temp);
        diagIndicies{numCells} = temp;
    end

    % Now go along bottom row...
    %fprintf('Diagonals along bottom are:\n');
    for y=cols-1:-1:1
        rowNum = rows;
        colNum = y;
        temp = [];
        while rowNum >= 1 && colNum >= 1
            temp = [temp; [rowNum colNum]];
            rowNum = rowNum - 1;
            colNum = colNum - 1;
        end
        numCells = numCells + 1;
        temp = flipud(temp); % Need row major order for assignment
        %disp(temp);
        diagIndicies{numCells} = temp;
    end

 end


 % Main function starts here.

[rows, cols] = size(A);

theMaxProduct = -10000000;
indicies = [];

if isscalar(A)
    if A == 1 && n == 1
        indicies = [1,1];
        return;
    else
        return;
    end
end



% Find max product in each row of A
for i=1:rows
    for j=1:cols-n+1
        theProduct = 1;
        for k=j:j+n-1
            theProduct = theProduct * A(i, k);
        end
        if theProduct > theMaxProduct
            theMaxProduct = theProduct;
            indicies = [];
            for k=j:j+n-1
                indicies = [indicies; [i, k]];
            end

        end
    end
end
fprintf('theMaxProduct after examining rows = %15.15f\n', theMaxProduct);

% Find max product in each column of A
for i=1:cols
    for j=1:rows-n+1
        theProduct = 1;
        for k=j:j+n-1
            theProduct = theProduct * A(k, i);
        end
        if theProduct > theMaxProduct
            theMaxProduct = theProduct;
            indicies = [];
            for k=j:j+n-1
                indicies = [indicies; [k, i]];
            end

        end
    end
end
fprintf('theMaxProduct after examining cols = %15.15f\n', theMaxProduct);



% Find max product along reverse diagonals of A
diagIndicies = getAllReverseDiagonalIndicies();
%disp(diagIndicies);
for i=1: length(diagIndicies)
    [numIndicies, ~] = size(diagIndicies{i});
    for j=1:numIndicies-n+1
        theProduct = 1;
        for k=j:j+n-1
            theProduct = theProduct * A(diagIndicies{i}(k, 1), diagIndicies{i}(k, 2));
        end
        if theProduct > theMaxProduct
            theMaxProduct = theProduct;
            indicies = [];
            for k=j:j+n-1
                indicies = [indicies; [diagIndicies{i}(k, 1), diagIndicies{i}(k, 2)]];
            end

        end
    end
end
fprintf('theMaxProduct after examining reverse diag = %15.15f\n', theMaxProduct);


% Find max product along diagonals of A
diagIndicies = getAllDiagonalIndicies();
%disp(diagIndicies);
for i=1: length(diagIndicies)
    [numIndicies, ~] = size(diagIndicies{i});
    for j=1:numIndicies-n+1
        theProduct = 1;
        for k=j:j+n-1
            theProduct = theProduct * A(diagIndicies{i}(k, 1), diagIndicies{i}(k, 2));
        end
        if theProduct > theMaxProduct
            theMaxProduct = theProduct;
            indicies = [];
            for k=j:j+n-1
                indicies = [indicies; [diagIndicies{i}(k, 1), diagIndicies{i}(k, 2)]];
            end

        end
    end
end
fprintf('theMaxProduct after examining main diag = %15.15f\n', theMaxProduct);
```

end

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that Matlab understands linear indexing into multi-dimensional matrices.  For OP's example of a `3*3` (let's call it `a`) matrix the expression `a(3)` identifies the same element as `a(3,1)` (Matlab uses column-major layout).  So, for a `k*k` matrix, the expression

```
[1, k+2, 2k+3, 3k+4, ...]
```

gives the indices of the elements on the main diagonal.  There is a range of ways to generate that vector.  Then, a judicious application of `ind2sub` will give the 2-d indices into the same matrix.

It shouldn't be too hard to generalise this approach to the other diagonals and to non-square matrices.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for the "northwest to southeast" diagonals.

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5;6,7,8,9,10;11,12,13,14,15];  
rows = size (A,1);   cols = size (A,2);   padding = rows - 1; 
padded = [ones(rows, padding), A, ones(rows, padding)];

% Create a Helper array containing column/row pairs and a product
Helper = zeros (cols + padding, rows * 2 + 1);
for i = 1 : cols + padding;  % i moves along columns of the padded array
  i0 = i - padding; % "actual" index w.r.t A, where leftmost index is 1-padding
  c  = 1;       % a counter used for filling current "Helper" row appropriately
  for j = 1 : rows;       % j moves along rows
    Helper(i, c)   = i0;  % store current "actual" column
    Helper(i, c+1) = j;   % store current row
    c  = c  + 2;          % move to next 2 slots in "Helper"
    i0 = i0 + 1;          % move to next "actual" column for processing
  end 

  % Process product at appropriate indices
  Helper(i, end) = prod (padded (sub2ind (       ...
                     size (padded),              ...
                     Helper(i,2:2:end-1),        ...
                     Helper(i,1:2:end-1)+padding ...
                   )));
end

% Isolate the correct indices for which the product is largest
[~, biggest] = max (Helper(:, end)); % column index of largest product in Helper
Pairs = reshape (Helper(biggest, 1:end-1), 2, []); % collect indices
Pairs = fliplr (Pairs.');                          % express as rows/cols

% Remove pairs where column occurs in the "padded" zone
for i = 1 : size (Pairs, 1)
  if Pairs(i, 1) < 1 || Pairs(i, 1) > cols; Pairs(i, :) = []; end
end

display(Pairs)
```

If you understand the logic behind this, the "NorthEast to SouthWest" diagonals should be a piece of cake to obtain too. I'll leave that for you to figure out :)

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for posting an answer, but I can't get it to run.  I get this:

Undefined function 'padarray' for input arguments of type 'double'.
Error in diagTest (line 3)
padded = padarray (A, [0, padding], 1, 'both');

I copied your code and put it into a .m file and ran it by typing in the name of that file.  Is that the right way to execute it?

Comment: ah, `padarray` is part of the `Image Processing Toolbox`, it appears you just have basic matlab. No worries, all it does is add a bunch of "zeros" or "ones" on each side. I've edited the code to do this manually. This is a script, so you can either run it as a file or just copy everything on your terminal, yes. (i.e. it's not a function! Your "input" matrix is just defined as the first line in the script)

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to do this is to construct an array the same shape as your input where the value of each element is its index. Then you can get the values (indices) of each diagonal.

```
function diag_cell = alldiags(A)    
   [m,n] = size(A);

   M = reshape(1:m*n, m, n);   % construct array of indices
   % there are (m-1) diagonals below the main (k parameter negative)
   %   and (n-1) diagonals above, plus 0 for the main diagonal
   for d = 1-m:n-1
      C1{d+m} = diag(M, d);   % store in C1{1}..C1{m+n-1}
   end

   % to get the antidiagonals, rotate the index matrix `M` and repeat
   %   (remember to swap `m` and `n`):
   M = rot90(M);
   for d = 1-n:m-1
      C2{d+n} = diag(M, d);
   end

   diag_cell = {C1{:}, C2{:}};   % concatenate the cell arrays and return
end
```

Here's a test run with the 3x3 sample matrix:

```
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

>> alldiags(A)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =  3
  [1,2] =

     2
     6

  [1,3] =

     1
     5
     9

  [1,4] =

     4
     8

  [1,5] =  7
  [1,6] =  1
  [1,7] =

     4
     2

  [1,8] =

     7
     5
     3

  [1,9] =

     8
     6

  [1,10] =  9
}
```

---

If you really have to, you can convert all of the indices to subscripts as you go, but if you're accessing the original matrix it's probably easier to do it with indices. Here's an example converting the main diagonal to subscripts:

```
>> C{3}
ans =

   1
   5
   9

>> [r,c] = ind2sub(size(A), C{3});
>> subs = [r c]
subs =

   1   1
   2   2
   3   3
```

---

Here's an example to illustrate why this works. Let's take a random 6x3 matrix `A`:

```
A =

   0.634825   0.560609   0.926716
   0.049504   0.226152   0.748278
   0.746754   0.493896   0.773868
   0.993245   0.457522   0.412092
   0.430003   0.695042   0.641917
   0.935298   0.960166   0.022872
```

The first thing the function does is get the size of the input matrix `A` and create a new matrix of the same size such that the value of each element is equal to its linear index. Linear indices start at `1` at subscript `[1,1]`, increase down the column to `m` at `[m,1]`, then go to `m+1` for subscript `[1,2]`, ending at index `m*n` at subscript `[m,n]`.

```
>> [m,n] = size(A)
m =  6
n =  3
>> M = reshape(1:m*n, m, n)
M =

    1    7   13
    2    8   14
    3    9   15
    4   10   16
    5   11   17
    6   12   18
```

The output `diag_cell` for this matrix looks like this (heavily reformatted so it's easier to see all at once):

```
diag_cell =
{
  [1,1]  =   6
  [1,2]  =   5    12
  [1,3]  =   4    11    18
  [1,4]  =   3    10    17
  [1,5]  =   2     9    16
  [1,6]  =   1     8    15
  [1,7]  =   7    14
  [1,8]  =  13
  [1,9]  =   1
  [1,10] =   7     2
  [1,11] =  13     8     3
  [1,12] =  14     9     4
  [1,13] =  15    10     5
  [1,14] =  16    11     6
  [1,15] =  17    12
  [1,16] =  18
}
```

The first half of the entries are the normal diagonals (top-left to bottom-right), and the second half are the antidiagonals (top-right to bottom-left).

As an example, take the diagonal `diag_cell{4} = [3; 10; 17]`. You can look at the matrix `M` to see which elements these indices refer to.

```
A =

   0.634825   0.560609   0.926716
   0.049504   0.226152   0.748278
  *0.746754*  0.493896   0.773868
   0.993245  *0.457522*  0.412092
   0.430003   0.695042  *0.641917*
   0.935298   0.960166   0.022872
```

This diagonal starts at `[3,1]` and ends at `[5,3]`. If we recover the values from `A`, we get:

```
>> A(diag_cell{4})
ans =

   0.74675
   0.45752
   0.64192
```

Comment: Umm thanks for this but I don't really understand it.  You have gotten all the diagonal values, but not the indexes of those diagonals as far as I can see? Tell me if I'm wrong? So for instance, for that main diagonal 1,5,9, I want the indexes of this i.e. [1,1; 2,2; 3,3].  And for the smaller diagonal of 4,8, I want [2 1; 3 2]

Comment: No, that's why I constructed the new matrix. Each entry of the new matrix is equal to its index. When you get the values of the diagonals, you get the indices of the diagonals. What you're calling indexes, `[1, 1; 2, 2; 3, 3]` are the subscripts that I mention above. You can recover those using `ind2sub` if you have to, but it depends on what you're doing with them later.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that for an explanation of linear indexing in MATLAB.

Comment: I've added an example of converting to subscripts. Of course, this can be added to the function itself if that's what you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks, does this work for non square matrices?  It doesn't seem to?

Comment: Yes, I've tested it with matrices where `m<n` and `m>n` as well as `m==n`. That's why I use both m and n, and swap them when I rotate the matrix. I've added an example that will hopefully clarify how the indices are generated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all your work, but I've tested this again, and it doesn't work for a row vector.  And seems to give the wrong answer for a 2x4 matrix too. With this: [1 2 3 4; 5 6 7 8] I get Columns 1 through 8 [2] [2x1 double] [2x1 double] [2x1 double] [7] [1] [2x1 double] [2x1 double] Columns 9 through 10 [2x1 double] [8].  2 is not a diagonal, nor is 7.  Am I missing something?

Comment: I'm getting incorrect answers on row vectors as well. I'll have a look at that and see what's going on. For the 2x4 matrix, that looks correct. Remember, the return values are the indices, not the matrix values. To get the value for index `7` you'd have to do `A(7)`.

Answer (score 0):

This solution goes all the way to your final task - finding the indices of the maximum product of any vector in the matrix:

```
function out = maxVecProd(A)
% validate the input is a vector\matrix:
assert(ismatrix(A),'Input must be a vector or matrix')
[cmax,cind] = max(prod(A,1)); % find where the maximum prod in the columns
[rmax,rind] = max(prod(A,2)); % find where the maximum prod in the rows
if all(size(A))>1 % if its a matrix:
    all_d = -(size(A,1)-1):(size(A,1)-1); % get all the valid diagonals
    pd = zeros(2*numel(all_d),2); % the solution of all products
    c = 1;
    for d = all_d
        pd(c,1) = prod(diag(A,d)); % get the diagonal product
        pd(c,2) = prod(diag(fliplr(A),d)); % get the anti-diagonal product
        c = c+1;
    end
    [dmax,dind] = max(pd(:)); % find where the maximum prod in the diagonals
    % get the orientation of the maximum prod (column, row, diagonal)
    [~,dirmax] = max([rmax,cmax,dmax]);
else
    [~,dirmax] = max([rmax,cmax]);
end
switch dirmax
    case 1
        % create the indices for the maximum row:
        out = [repelem(rind,size(A,2)).' (1:size(A,2)).'];
    case 2
        % create the indices for the maximum column:
        out = [(1:size(A,1)).' repelem(cind,size(A,1)).'];
    case 3
        [r,dir] = ind2sub(size(pd),dind); % convert to [row,column]
        d_ind = all_d(r); % find which value of d gave the maximum product
        [R,C] = ndgrid(1:size(A,1),1:size(A,2)); % create a grid of all indices
        if dir==1
            % find the indices for a diagonal:
            out = [diag(R,d_ind),diag(C,d_ind)];
        else
            % find the indices for an anti-diagonal:
            out = [diag(fliplr(R),d_ind),diag(fliplr(C),d_ind)];
        end
end
end
```

and you get for `maxVecProd(A)`:

```
out =
     1     2
     2     2
     3     2
```

which means the largest prod  in is of the elements in (1,2), (2,2) and (3,2).

Comment: What value do you have for n in this example please?  In the problem n refers to the number of elements to be multiplied together.  So it might be a 4x6 matrix but only 3 numbers in any row, col, or diagonal are multiplied together to form a product, for instance. So then a window of 3 slides along each row, col, or diagonal.

Comment: I guess I should have said that at the start, but it's why I've been asking for the subscripts (or indicies or whatever).  So I can then perform the last bit of the calculation.... gah.

Comment: Hi, this is close but it doesn't work for 1D vectors, I get this: 
Assignment has more non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts

Error in diagTest2 (line 12)
    pd(c,1) = prod(diag(A,d)); % get the diagonal product

Comment: Right, I have edited the answer to includes that case. I also added a check that `A` is not an ND-array (more than 2D) where a diagonal is not defined, and warped everything in a function. Feel free to ask for any part that is not clear ;)