# Find the indices of elements of matrix that form the maximum product

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I have a task to find the maximum product of elements in a matrix. The input arguments are the matrix and the scalar n that tells me how many elements to multiply. If n=2, then I should multiply two by two. The maximum product can lie either in rows, or in columns on in diagonal. For example in this case A's elements were multiplied 2 by 2 along rows (B) and columns (C).

```
A =
   8     1     6
   3     5     7
   4     9     2
B =
      8.0000    6.0000
     15.0000   35.0000
     36.0000   18.0000
C =
     24.0000    5.0000   42.0000
     12.0000   45.0000   14.0000
```

I do it using the loop

```
    c=[]
for ii = 1:(length(A)-n+1)
    p = prod(A(:,ii:ii+n-1));
    c=[c p];
end
```

or

```
for i=1:size(A,2)
      B(i,:)=real(exp(conv(log(A(i,:)),ones(1,n),'valid')));
      C(:,i)=real(exp(conv(log(A(:,i)),ones(1,n),'valid')));
end
```

In both cases I receive the product but when it comes to getting the maximum among that products, (in my case that is the product of **A(2,2)*A(3,2)=45**) I cannot find the indices of original matrix elements that formed that product, i.e. (2,2) and (3,2).

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How does this work for N=3? Would you take B and then multiply across rows and columns to form BB =[48 525 648] and BC = [120 210; 540 630]? Or do you go back to the original matrix?

Comment: No we start always from original A matrix. The `n` is an input argument and it shows the number of elements I should take for multiplication. In case  `n=3` we get `B =48.0000 105.0000 72.0000` and `C =96.0000 45.0000 84.0000` In this case the max is 105 which is the product of `A(3,1)*A(3,2)*A(3,3)`

Comment: Last bits of clarification; let's say your input is the row vector [2 2 1 2]. Is the correct answer for n=3 4, or is it 8? [Do the numbers need to be in a line?]. If the input is [1 0; 0 1] is the answer for n=2 0? You seem to only multiply through rows or columns, but this doesn't necessarily yield the maximum product in the matrix

Comment: for row vector [2 2 1 2] and n=4 the answer is 8 and there is no column product. My input will be a matrix. If the input is [1 0; 0 1]  and n=2 the  answer is 0 . I need not the max product but the indices that formed that product.

Comment: You may want to look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39315814/iterate-over-diagonal-elements-of-a-matrix-in-matlab/39336063#39336063) on a similiar task.

Answer (score 1):

The information can be worked out from knowing where, in B or C, the maximum value occurs.  This is returned by the max function as a second argument, albeit in index form.  I've tried out your code for producing B and C, and it doesn't seem to produce what you've got, HOWEVER, assuming that you've got some way of producing B and C as in the first part of your question, the following code will return (r1,c1) and (r2,c2) the reference to the two multiplicands (assuming that there is only one maximum - you really do need to check for this):

```
[maxB,IB]=max(B(:));
[maxC,IC]=max(C(:));
if (maxB>maxC)
    [r1,c1]=ind2sub(size(B),IB);
    r2=r1; c2=c1+n-1;
else
    [r1,c1]=ind2sub(size(C),IC);
    r2=r1+n-1; c2=c1;
end
```

I'm not quite sure whether n is a distance, in which case:

```
B=A(:,1:end-n+1).*A(:,n:end);
C=A(1:end-n+1,:).*A(n:end,:);
```

or whether you mean to take the product of all terms within n of the starting point.  Either way, the maximum can be found using the above code.

Comment: The answer is good but only adapted to  `n=2`. The n is an input argument and it shows the number of elements I should take for multiplication. In case `A=[ 8 1 6;3 5 7;4 9 2]` and `n=3` I get `B =48.0000 105.0000 72.0000` and `C =96.0000   45.0000   84.0000`
In this case the max is 105 which is the product of `A(3,1)*A(3,2)*A(3,3)`

Comment: That's a fair point!  To deal with n>2, change the two commands within the if statement to `c2=c1+n-1` in the first condition, and `r2=r1+n-1` in the else clause.

Answer (score 1):

Given inputs A and n, and assuming you don't care which output you give in case of a tie,

```
%Setup
[r, c] = size(A)
if r <= n
    maxProd = prod(A(1:n,1),1);
elseif c <= n
    maxProd = prod(A(1,1:n),2);
else 
    return
end

indOut = zeros(n, 2);
dirOut = 0;

%Check verticals 
for ii = 1:(r-n+1)
    for jj = 1:c
         testProd = prod(A(ii:ii+n-1,jj),1);
         if testProd > maxProd
             maxProd = testProd;
             indOut(1,:) = [ii jj];
             dirOut = 1;
         end
    end
end

%Check horizontals
for ii = 1:r
    for jj = 1:(c-n+1)
         testProd = prod(A(ii,jj:jj+n-1),2);
         if testProd > maxProd
             maxProd = testProd;
             indOut(1,:) = [ii jj];
             dirOut = 2;
         end
    end
end

%Set output
for ii = 2:n
    if dirOut == 1;
        indOut(1,n) = indOut(1,n-1) + 1;
    else
        indOut(2,n) = indOut(2,n-1) + 1;
    end
end
```

If you do care about ties, you'll have to add additional outputs to the side of the indOut matrix