# MATLAB: Applying vectors of row and column indices without looping

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a situation analogous to the following

```
z = magic(3)  % Data matrix

y = [1 2 2]' % Column indices
```

So,

```
z =      
       8 1 6               
       3 5 7      
       4 9 2
```

`y` represents the column index I want for each row. It's saying I should take row 1 column 1, row 2 column 2, and row 3 column 2. The correct output is therefore `8 5 9`.

I worked out I can get the correct output with the following

```
x = 1:3;
for i = 1:3
    result(i) = z(x(i),y(i));
end
```

However, is it possible to do this without looping?

Comment: Relevant read: [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two other possible ways I can suggest is to use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to find the linear indices that you can use to sample the matrix directly:

```
z = magic(3);
y = [1 2 2];
ind = sub2ind(size(z), 1:size(z,1), y);
result = z(ind);
```

We get:

```
>> result

result =

     8     5     9
```

Another way is to use `sparse` to create a sparse matrix which you can turn into a `logical` matrix and then sample from the matrix with this `logical` matrix.

```
 s = sparse(1:size(z,1), y, 1, size(z,1), size(z,2)) == 1; % Turn into logical
 result = z(s);
```

We also get:

```
>> result

result =

     8
     5
     9
```

Be advised that this only works provided that each row index linearly increases from 1 up to the end of the rows.  This conveniently allows you to read the elements in the right order taking advantage of the column-major readout that MATLAB is based on.  Also note that the output is also a column vector as opposed to a row vector.

The link posted by Adriaan is a great read for the next steps in accessing elements in a vectorized way:  [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that).

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to do this, one interesting way is to directly work out the indexes you want:

```
 v = 0:size(y,2)-1; %generates a number from 0 to the size of your y vector -1
 ind = y+v*size(z,2); %generates the indices you are looking for in each row
 zinv = z';
 zinv(ind) 

 >> ans =

 8     5     9
```

Comment: Using `sub2ind` may be easier to read.... but your code is essentially doing what `sub2ind` is doing.