# Filtering the DetectSURFfeatures and converting the array back to its own type on MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matlab-cvst, surf

I'm supposed to gather a bunch of SURF points from a video frame and after filtering these coordinate points bunch I'd like to convert it back to it's own form. 
Below you can see the code I wrote:

```
surfpoints_raw_single_column_matrix = detectSURFFeatures(img);
raw_points_double_column_matrix = SURFPoints(Location);
s=1;
for a=1:size(raw_points_double_column_matrix,1)
    i=raw_points_double_column_matrix(a,1);
    j=raw_points_double_column_matrix(a,2);
if ( (i>156-9-70 && i<156+9+70) && (j>406-9-70 && j<406+9+70) )
matrix_filtered(s,1)=i;
matrix_filtered(s,2)=j;
s=s+1; %filtered matrix index counter
end
end
???? = matrix_filtered; 
% Conversion back to the type of surfpoints_raw_single_column_matrix
```

What I need is to convert (for example) 24x2 matrix into a 24x1 matrix which still keeps the selected x and y coordinates as a pair ( 24 times [x,y] ).
Thanks in advance...

Comment: Hi! try to add a [mcve], so we can test the code. However I dot understand what you want. Surf features will give you some specific `x,y` coordinates of pixels, that have some SURF values. What conversion is happenning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble with that approach is that you would be losing all of the information that accompanied the SURF descriptor per point.  You would lose information such as the scale, the sign of the Laplacian at each point, the orientation, etc.  You are only looking at the spatial locations.

Instead, use `logical` indexing and remove out any of the points in the `SURFPoints` structure array you don't want.  You are also not getting the raw coordinates properly.  Remember that `SURFPoints` contains the spatial locations of your detected features in a field called `Location` which is what you tried to do in your second line of code but it isn't quite correct.

Therefore, what you need to do is the following:

```
% Your code
surfpoints_raw_single_column_matrix = detectSURFFeatures(img);

% Corrected
raw_points_double_column_matrix = surfpoints_raw_single_column_matrix.Location;

% New - Get X and Y coordinates
X = raw_points_double_column_matrix(:,1);
Y = raw_points_double_column_matrix(:,2);

% New - Determine a mask to grab the points we want
ind = (X>156-9-70 & X<156+9+70) & (Y>406-9-70 & Y<406+9+70);

% New - Create new SURFPoints structure that contains all information
% from the points we need
matrix_filtered = surfpoints_raw_single_column_matrix(ind);
```

Comment: Thanks so much that helped a lot! I didn't even know that i can manipulate surf command with (ind) additon.

Comment: @CanDemir ah :) Logical indexing is a MATLAB staple.  Because what is returned by `detectSURFFeatures` is a structure array, you can index into it just like any other matrix or array in MATLAB.  Logical indexing here is important because you want to retain all of the characteristics of each feature point.  Copying over just the spatial locations would lose all of that important information that makes SURF special.  BTW, you're very welcome and good luck!

Comment: @CanDemir As a detour, I highly recommend this post on discussing about indexing: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that - It explains about logical indexing in more detail, as well as linear indexing which is its grandfather.

Comment: How do I import `detectSURFFeatures`, in matplot python?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare There is no such functionality in `matplotlib`.  You can get out of box SURF by using OpenCV.

Comment: @rayryeng , In opencv also I have look into `cv2.xfeatures2d.SURF` but it seems they have also removed from there.

Comment: @rayryeng, any otherway I can use it in opencv?

Comment: @PiyushS.Wanare You are wayyyy behind in keeping up to date with OpenCV developments. In OpenCV 3.x, the non-free modules have all moved to the `contrib` repo.  They are not included in OpenCV by default: https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.  If you're on Ubuntu for example, this is easily solved by: `pip install opencv-contrib-python`.  In Windows, download Christoph Gohlke's built wheel and install it: https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#opencv. 
 If neither work, you must build OpenCV from source and ensure you include the `contrib` repo when you build it.