# How to find all the pixels within some distance from a given pixel?

Tags: matlab, distance

How can I efficiently find all pixels `(u',v')` within a distance `x` from a given pixel `(u,v)`. Specifically all `(u',v')` such that `sqrt((u-u')^2 +(v-v')^2) <= x`

Comment: Its almost impossible to find `sqrt((u-u')^2 +(v-v')^2) = x` because pixels are at integer locations! Unless you interpolate

Comment: Yes you are right. I meant to ask `<= x`. I have modified the question. Apologies for the confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find all pixels at distance `x` you can use this indexing trick (for Manhattan distance)

```
u=10;v=10;
x=3.4;
pixels=img([floor(u-x) ceil(u+x)],[floor(v-x) ceil(v+x)]);
```

However, note that this will add any pixel that is within the distance, even if its just a piece of the pixel! E.g. (6,6) is inside!

---

For Euclidean distance, you need to define a circle around the point

```
[xi,yi]=meshgrid(1:size(img,1),1:size(img,2));
mask=sqrt((xi-u).^2+(yi-v).^2)<x; % or ceil(x)
pixel_values=img(mask);
[pixel_indices_u pixel_indices_v]=find(mask);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
u = rand(1e2,1); % Create a 100 random points in the unit square
v = rand(1e2,1); % Create a 100 random points in the unit square
a = 0.3; % Choosen pixel
b = 0.4;
x = 0.1; % radius from the choosen pixel

idx = (sqrt((u-a).^2 +(v-b).^2) <= x); % Create a logical index array
locs = [u(idx) v(idx)]; % Index the locations
```

This is basically exactly what you describe in the question, with the points being labelled as `(u,v)` and the "destination point" so to speak labelled with `(a,b)` as a prime (`'`) denotes the complex conjugate transpose in MATLAB.

Read more on logical indexing in [this very insightful answer by Luis Mendo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)