# Mark 1D-array in a 2D-plot

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary, plot, marker

I have a noisy periodic signal in Matlab that I've extracted peaks from with the help of `[peak loc]=findpeaks(signal)`. However unrealistic outliers are also inside the `peak` array.
I set min- and max-values  for `peak` and so get a shorter `peak` array. Now I would love to mark this shorter subset of original `peak` into the original `plot(loc,peak)`, whereat I'd get an error, since `loc` has kept its original length.

My questions:

- Is there a way in the fashion of a container.map or something similar that allows to adapt `loc` to `peak` with consistence of the loc-peak assignments?

  - How can I alternatively plot the shortened `peak` array onto the original signal plot?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can solve your problem with following code:

```
[peak,loc] = findpeaks(signal);
max_thr = 2;
min_thr = 1e-5;    
mask = peak>min_thr&peak<max_thr;
plot(loc(mask),peak(mask))
```

Is this what you want ?

Comment: Wow thanks, didn't know of that masking idea! Tesekkürler!

Comment: How can I read further on this idea? Is there a term for this technique?

Comment: Rica ederim :) Actually it is very common approach to use mask idea in MATLAB. I recommend you to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that this site for further information about indexing.