# Split the histogram into two regions

Tags: matlab

I want to divide the histogram into two regions (by taking the avg intensity value of histogram image).

```
hR = imhist(redChannel);
minRed = min(redChannel(:));
maxRed = max(redChannel(:));
avgRed = (minRed+maxRed)/2;
hlowR = hR(1:avgRed);
hhighR = hR(avgRed:256);
```

hlowR is giving the values but hhighR is empty. I don't know what's wrong. Please help. Thanks

Comment: Whats the value of `avgRed`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
hR = imhist(redChannel);
% minRed = min(redChannel(:));
% maxRed = max(redChannel(:));
% avgRed = (minRed+maxRed)/2;
avgRed = mean(redChannel(:)); % get mean directly
hlowR = hR(hR<=avgRed); % Logical index to find all values below the average
hhighR = hR(hR>=avgRed);% Logical index to find all values above the average
```

You are using `avgRed` directly as index, whilst you should check whether a value of `hR` is above or below it, using [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please tell me how can I perform histogram stretching on each region.?

Comment: @BENISHAMIN that's another question, so please make a separate post on Stack Overflow, keeping in mind the rules of [ask], so do try something yourself before posting here.