# Histogram division and stretching

Tags: matlab

I want to create under enhanced and over enhanced images by dividing the histogram into two regions (by taking the avg intensity value of histogram image) and perform histogram stretching on both the regions.

```
    rgbImage=imread('2.jpg');
    redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);
    hR = imhist(redChannel);
    minRed = min(redChannel(:));
    maxRed = max(redChannel(:));
    avgRed = (minRed+maxRed)/2;
    hlowR = hR(1:avgRed);
    hhighR = hR(avgRed:255);
```

Now, how I stretch both `hlowR` and `hhighR`?

Comment: This code doesn't work, as evidenced by your [former question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41546973/5211833). Also, why didn't you try anything, like I asked you to in [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41546973/split-the-histogram-into-two-regions/41547609?noredirect=1#comment70336374_41547609), citing the [ask] page of the help centre?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question, here is a code that can solve your question:

```
%open the image
rgbImage=imread('image.jpg');
redChannel = rgbImage(:, :, 1);

%calculate the median
minRed = min(redChannel(:));
maxRed = max(redChannel(:));
MedRed = (minRed+maxRed)/2;

%Histogram equalization on the first part of the histogram.
hlowR = redChannel;
hlowR(~ismember(redChannel,0:MedRed )) = 0;
hlowR = double(hlowR);
hlowR = uint8(((hlowR-min(hlowR(:)))./(max(hlowR(:))-min(hlowR(:))))*255);

%Histogram equalization on the second half part of the histogram.
hhighR = redChannel;
hhighR(~ismember(redChannel,MedRed :255)) = MedRed ;
hhighR = double(hhighR);
hhighR = uint8(((hhighR-min(hhighR(:)))./(max(hhighR(:))-min(hhighR(:))))*255);

%display the result
imagesc(hhighR)
figure
imagesc(hlowR)
```