# How do I combine the coordinate pairs of an array into a single index?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have an array

```
A = [3, 4; 5, 6; 4, 1];
```

Is there a way I could convert all coordinate pairs of the array into linear indices such that:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]'
```

whereby (3,4), (5,6), and (4,1) are represented by 1, 2, and 3, respectively.
Many thanks!

The reason I need is because I need to loop through array A such that I could make use of **each** coordinate pairs (3,4), (5,6), and (4,1) at the same time. This is because I will need to feed each of these pairs into a function so as to make another computation. See pseudo code below:

```
for ii = 1: length(A);
   [x, y] = function_obtain_coord_pairs(A);
   B      = function_obtain_fit(x, y, I);
end
```

whereby, at `ii = 1`, `x=3` and `y=4`. The next iteration takes the pair `x=5`, `y=6`, etc.

Basically what will happen is that my kx2 array will be converted to a kx1 array. Thanks for your help.

Comment: `A(1,:)` is `[3,4]`. Same with the othres

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)

Comment: Thanks @Ander Biguri. I see your point. What i want however is another array `A2 = [1, 2, 3]'` which stores all the linear indices of the original array pairs.

Comment: `A(A2(1),:)` but I dont see the point. Also, linear indices are a different thing. `A(2)` is `4`

Comment: @oma11 but are the linear indices not just `1:length(A)`?

Comment: I have to agree with @AnderBiguri. I'm not sure what is being asked here. There are many resources available for understanding how to index matrices. Also, this looks like a homework problem.

Comment: Your edit just made clear that what you want is my first comment. Replace  `function_obtain_coord_pairs(A);` with `x=A(i,1); y=A(i,2)`. Also, change the for loop to `i=1:size(A,1)`

Comment: @Ander Biguri i appreciate. Please could kindly explain to me why i needed to use size(A, 1) and not length(A)?. Cheers!

Comment: You can read that in the documentation. If you are lazy, try it yourself. Check what `size(A,1)` returns and what `length(A)` returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting your code, what you want was suggested by @Ander in the comments...

**Your code**

```
for ii = 1:length(A);
    [x, y] = function_obtain_coord_pairs(A);
    B      = function_obtain_fit(x, y, I);
end
```

**Adapted code**

```
for ii = 1:size(A,1);
    x = A(ii, 1);
    y = A(ii, 2);
    B = function_obtain_fit(x, y, I); % is I here supposed to be ii? I not defined...
end
```

Your unfamiliarly with indexing makes me think your `function_obtain_fit` function could probably be vectorised to accept the entire matrix `A`, but that's a matter for another day!

For instance, you really don't need to define `x` or `y` at all...

**Better code**

```
for ii = 1:size(A,1);
    B = function_obtain_fit(A(ii, 1), A(ii, 2), I);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a corrected version for your code:

```
A = [3, 4; 5, 6; 4, 1];
for k = A.'
    B = function_obtain_fit(k(1),k(2),I)
end
```

By iterating directly on `A` you iterate over the columns of `A`. Because you want to iterate over the rows we need to take `A.'`. So if we just display `k` it is:

```
for k = A.'
    k
end
```

the output is:

```
k =
     3
     4
k =
     5
     6
k =
     4
     1
```

Comment: Ok!. Thank you all for your suggestions and contributions. It seems what i want is probably not clear enough. I will try to make that clear just now.

Comment: @oma11 I have edited the answer to fit your question