# Matab indexing matrix rows with index vector

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

I'm trying to split data into a training and testing set. The data X is a 150x4 matrix of 150 data points with 4 features each. I did this to create an index vector to randomly select 100 out of 150 data points for training:

```
trainIndices = zeros(length(X),1);
trainIndices(randperm(150,100)) = 1
```

Then I tried doing this to select the rows where `trainIndices == 1`:

```
X_train = X(trainIndices,:);
```

But I'm getting an error `Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.`

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `trainIndices` includes some zeros which aren't valid indices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `trainIndices` is of type `double`, MATLAB is trying to treat the values as indices. Instead, you'll want to explicitly cast `trainIndices` as a `logical` matrix so that it can be used to perform logical indexing

```
trainIndices = false(length(X),1);
trainIndices(randperm(150,100)) = true;

X_train = X(trainIndices,:);
```

Or you can use your existing `trainIndices` and cast it

```
X_train = X(logical(trainIndices),:);
```

I would recommend the first approach since the `logical` array will take up less memory than the `double` array.

Comment: Thanks that worked will accept this answer as soon as it allows

Comment: I'd link to http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/matlab/750/vectorization/9514/logical-masking#t=201702161856275395681 to help clarify this technique.

Answer (score 2):

Indexing in MATLAB can be either `linear` or `logical` or a combination of them. Linear indexing is the regular indexing as C/C++ using integer numbers `[1,n]` (with n being vector length). 
Here you've tried to use a double vector (`trainIndices`) for logical indexing and since there is no element with index 0 MATLAB throws an error. The problem is solved through the following logical conversion:

```
X_train = X(trainIndices>0,:);
```

For more info on indexing you might see:

http://matlabtricks.com/post-23/tutorial-on-matrix-indexing-in-matlab

and

[Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that/32379806#32379806)

Comment: @LuisMendo, I think you're right , they are not completely separate things. I'll modify the answer and steal some parts of your comment!