# Zero out some of the smallest elements of a vector without disturbing the order

Tags: matlab, vector

Say I have a vector of size 1-*by*-`x` called `X`. I need to keep the 10 percent largest elements of `X` and set all other elements equal to zero. This is easy with using `sort`:

```
X = sort(abs(X),'descend');
DIM = floor(length(X)*(0.1));
X(DIM+1:end) = 0;
```

but disturbing the order of the original vector `X` is not allowed (or if I disturb the original order, after zeroing out, I should recover the original order which I don't know how to). How can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`prctile`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/prctile.html) function to find the 10% you're looking for, and then use [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) to set the rest to `0`:

```
X = rand(1e4,1);
TenPrc = prctile(X,90);
X(X<TenPrc) = 0;
```

Comment: @Adriaan , I am quite sure that `prctile` works by sorting the values, so it does the same internally as Zep does explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

The `sort` function gives you back the indexes of the sorted array:

```
DIM = floor(length(X)*(0.9));
[X, idx] = sort(abs(X)); 
X(1:DIM+1) = 0;

% Restore original indexes
X = X(idx);
```