# Variation of indices of an array or matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, cumulative-sum

If I use this syntax:

```
mX=[1:5];
A=rand(5,1);
C(mX)=sum(A(1:mX));
```

Why doesn't the content of `C(mX)` vary with varying `mX`?

Instead of doing

```
C(1)=A(1) 
C(2)=A(1)+A(2), etc
```

it does:

```
C(1)=A(1)
C(2)=A(1)
C(3)=A(1), etc
```

Is there any way to vary `C(mX)` without resorting to a loop?

Comment: i think you are looking for `cumsum`: https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question:

```
mX=1:5;
A=rand(5,1);
C(mX)=sum(A(1:mX));
```

makes the sum over `A(1:[1 2 3 4 5])`, which results in `A(1:1)`, and hence all your `C(mX)` values will be filled with purely the element `A(1)`.

What you want to do is make a *cumulative sum*, which can be done, as [@leanderMoesinger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44903131/variation-of-indexs-of-an-array-or-matrix#comment76783315_44903131) mentioned with [`cumsum`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cumsum.html?s_tid=doc_ta):

```
A=rand(5,1);
C = cumsum(A)
C =
    0.0975
    0.3760
    0.9229
    1.8804
    2.8453
```

If you want to learn more about indexing I can highly recommend the following post: [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833)

If you want not all elements of `A`, but e.g. up to element three you can do

```
mX = 1:3;
A = rand(5,1);
C = cumsum(A(mX)); calculate only to mX

mX = [1 3 5];
C = cumsum(A(mX)) % Also works if you only want elements 1 3 and 5 to appear

% If you want elements of C 1 3 and 5 use 
tmp = cumsum(A);
C = tmp(mX);
```

Comment: Thank you for answer . But I still have a question : Supposing  that I will do an operation that will include matrixs instead of arrays (for example `C(mX,mY)=sum(sum(A(1:mX,1:mY).*B(2:mX+1,2:mY+1)))` How can I vary mX and mY ? ( It will do this operation only for mX=mY=1))

Comment: @user1021 the size of the two matrices after indexing needs to be equal in order to work. Presumably your indices don't guarantee that. But if you have a different question (which this is, as it is about element wise matrix multiplication, the sum is just fluff) please ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by `cumsum` like so:

```
mX=[1:5];
A=rand(5,1);
C = cumsum(A(mX));
```

Comment: Now the last line is redundant; as `C = cumsum(A)` contains 5 elements, and doing `C = C(1:5)` is thus a mere operation saying `C = C`.

Comment: It might change the `mX`. It is a general solution.

Comment: For example if you change `mX` to `[1:4]` the solution could work!