# Indexing in isnan

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

While using the `isnan(x)` operator, I notice that the output is an array with `0`s and `1`s corresponding whether the element is `NaN` or not.

The logical way to filter out NaN elements would be `x(find(~isnan(x)))`, as `find()` returns the indices. As a suprise to me, `x(~isnan(x))` also gives the same result.

On checking, `~isnan(x)` is just an array of 1s and 0s, and for the simple case of `x = rand(10,1)`, I get `all(~isnan(x) == ones(10, 1))` as true. But when I run `x(ones(10, 1))`, I get an array with just the first element of `x` repeated 10 times, as expected.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have a look at [logical indexing](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html#bq7egb6-1)

Comment: Also, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Comment: `x(true(10, 1))` WILL give you `x` back, however.

Comment: Note that MATLAB may behave differently depending on the data type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MATLAB uses multiple type of indices.

`isnan` returns logical indices. That is, a matrix or vector of size `x` where it is `1` if that element is `nan`. The output is logical "binary" variable

`find` looks for any element that is not `0` and gives you its index. The output are integers.

As such, both outputs can be used as indices so they will the same result. That being said, if you don't need the actual indices (which you don't in your example above), don't use it. `find` is slow and redundant in the case above.

Now if you create the arrays of `1`s like you did above, it treats it as an index (like `find`) so it returns the value of the first element 10 times. The reason is that the functions `ones` does not return a logical variable but actual numbers (real). If you substitute `ones` with `true` or convert the results into binary first, it will be treat it as logical indices.