# Trouble in making a sub-matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have this matrix:

```
mpc.bus = [100  1   170 100 0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
110 3   50  30  0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
120 2   80  45  0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
130 1   200 110 0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
140 1   30  8   0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9]
```

I want to create a sub-matrix that obeys the following rule:
if the value of the second column is equal to 3 or 2, a new matrix (called `MatrixPVREF`) will receive the 1st, 2nd, 3rd and 4th column of `mpc.bus`.

This is the result I would like to obtain:

```
MatrixPVREF = [110  3   50  30;
120 2   80  45]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
mpc.bus = [100  1   170 100 0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
110 3   50  30  0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
120 2   80  45  0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
130 1   200 110 0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9;
140 1   30  8   0   0   1   1   0   230 1   1.1 0.9];

tmp2 = mpc.bus(mpc.bus(:,2)==2,:);
tmp3 = mpc.bus(mpc.bus(:,2)==3,:);

MatrixPVREF = [tmp3(1:4); tmp2(1:4)]


MatrixPVREF =

   110     3    50    30    
   120     2    80    45
```

Shorter:

```
MatrixPVREF = mpc.bus(mpc.bus(:,2)==2 | mpc.bus(:,2)==3,1:4);
```

Using [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that) into `mpc.bus`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [***`ismember`***](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to check if the elements in the second column equal to 2 or 3. Use [*matrix indexing*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html) to do the rest.

```
MatrixPVREF = mpc.bus(ismember(mpc.bus(:,2),[2 3]),1:4);
```

```
>> MatrixPVREF

MatrixPVREF =

   110     3    50    30    
   120     2    80    45
```