# In MATLAB, how to find indexes in vector every time value change from 1 to 0?

Tags: matlab, vector, indexing

I have a vector of 1s and 0s that represent when an intermittent data signal is occurring. E.g.:

```
    V = [0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0];
```

How do I find the index value of every change from 1 to 0?
So for vector V above, the answer would be:

```
    idx = [10,18,28];
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quick and easy:

```
idx=find(diff(V)<0)+1;
```

Compute the derivative, get only the negative values (from 1 to 0 is -1) and find the locations. As the derivatives start from the second location, we need to add 1

However, note that if what you want is accessing data on those locations, it's better to use the logical indices directly, as in:

```
somevals=my_other_data([false;diff(V)<0]);
```

Read more about general variable indexing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that)

Answer (score 6):

[`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) is more than just strings and also suitable for situations like yours.

```
idx = strfind(V,[1 0]) + 1;
```

Comment: I often forget how versatile `strfind` is.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a convolution:

```
idx = find(conv(V,[-1,1])==1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want a generic solution which works for "index of every time the value changes from `x` to `y`", use this vectorised approach:

```
idx = find( ( V(1:end-1) == x ) & V(2:end) == y ) ) + 1;
```

In your case

```
idx = find( ( V(1:end-1) == 1 ) & ( V(2:end) == 0 ) ) + 1;
% >> idx = [10 18 28]
```

---

As with Ander's solution, if you're using this for indexing then `find` is an unnecessary slow-down, just use this

```
idx = [false, ( V(1:end-1) == 1 ) & ( V(2:end) == 0 )];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `find` to locate 0's and 1's and use `intersect` to find edges, in general

```
>> intersect(find(V==0), find(V==1)+1)
ans =
    10    18    28
```

You can replace 0 and 1 with any arbitrary value. But if you are dealing with only 0's and 1's you can simplify it to

```
>> intersect(find(~V), find(V)+1)
ans =
    10    18    28
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to write a loop. It's been a while since I've used matlab so forgive me if my syntax is a bit off, but something with similar logic to this should work:

Given your vector V:

```
idx = [];
for i = 1:(length(V) - 1)
  if (V(i) == 0 && V(i+1) == 1)
    idx = [idx, (i + 1)];
  end
end
```

Good luck! Let me know if it doesn't work for some reason. If you're going to be performing this actions a lot, you should probably write a function too.

Comment: This works, but definitely very far from the easiest way in MATLAB. This is good for C

Comment: This exact logic [can be vectorised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51745032/3978545), make the most of the native MATLAB functionality!