# How to loop through an n x n matrix and replace values in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an n x n matrix in MATLAB. I am trying to iterate through each row and column of this matrix. If the value in each element is higher than a certain threshold, I want to replace that element with a 1. If the value in each element is lower than a certain threshold, I want to replace that element with a 0.

I am trying to use two for loops, but it's not leading me anywhere.Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your code, so we can point out the problem.

Comment: Your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest logical indexing.

```
A = randi([1 20],6,6);
Threshhold = 13;
A(A<Threshhold) = 0;
A(A>=Threshhold) = 1;
```

Before:

```
>> A = randi([1 20],6,6)
A =
     7     1    20     3     2    15
    16    13    11     3    11     7
     5     2     1     5    10    16
     5    14     8    14    11     8
    16    11     7    20    20    17
    10     1     2    10     6    12
```

After:

```
>> A
A =
     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     1     1     1     0     1     1
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Hope that helps.

**Update:**
Per @Cris Luengo from comments, 
Other approaches include `A=double(A>=Threshold)` or equivalently `A=+(A>=Threshold)`.

Comment: Might as well do `A=double(A>=Threshold)`. Or equivalently `A=+(A>=Threshold)`.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo, hadn't seen those approaches before. Updated the answer to include with attribution.