# What is the name of this Matlab operator?

Tags: matlab

I came across this [code](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/313102-how-to-detect-peaks-above-a-certain-threshold-in-matlab) during some troubleshooting in Matlab when trying to find peaks of a signal:

```
minValue = min(yourSignal);
yourSignal(yourSignal < threshold) = minValue;
```

What I think it does is put the minimum element in the vector `yourSignal` in the first line. And then the next line I'm not sure what's happening, but it seems to assign `yourSignal` with any element less than `threshold` in the vector `yourSignal`. I don't understand what the assignment to `minValue` does.

Please explain to me what this code does or tell me the name of the operation in the second line so that I can find its documentation.

Comment: You might find [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/3372061) helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/). You could break it into 2 operations

```
Idx = yourSignal < threshold;
```

That creates a logical array (true or false), which is true when the signal array is less than the threshold.

```
yourSignal(Idx) = minValue;
```

Anywhere that `Idx` is true, replace that element with `minValue`.

Comment: great, thanks! i'm not particularly versed in matlab, so it's difficult to search something if you don't know the name of it. for posterity: https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/

Comment: No worries, it certainly can be! Added your link to the answer.