# How to plot a surface plot with constraints

Tags: matlab, plot, constraints

I'm trying to plot a function subject to three constraints (see code)

Now I tried the following

```
function value = example(x1, x2)

if x1 < 0 || x2 < 0 || x1+2*x2 > 6
    value = NaN;
else 
    value = abs(x1 - x2) + exp(-x1 - x2); 
end

[X, Y] = meshgrid(-10:10, -10:10);
Z = example(X,Y);
surf(X, Y, Z)
```

Now, this raises an error since the if clause cannot be evaluated for inputs X and Y. Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: You should read this generic answer on indexing: [Linear indexing, logical indexing, and all that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that). In short, you need to use logical indexing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cris mentioned, use [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/).

The basic idea is `(x1 < 0 | x2 < 0 | x1+2*x2 > 6)` will gives you a matrix (same size as `value`) of zeros and ones. The positions of ones correspond to the true condition. Try this:

```
function value = example(x1, x2)
value = abs(x1 - x2) + exp(-x1 - x2); 
value(x1 < 0 | x2 < 0 | x1+2*x2 > 6) = NaN;
```

Output:

[image]