# Applying threshold to an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write a function that thresholds a grey-level image `F` and a threshold value `t` (`0 ≤ t ≤ 255`) such that `r = 0` for `r < t` and `r = 255` otherwise.

I have tried to implement this, but `imshow(r)` does not produce an output.

```
function f = imgThreshold(img, t)

f = img;

if (f < t)
    f = 0;
else
    f = 1;
end

img = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/kP0u2.png');
t = 20; 
r = imgThreshold(img, t);
imshow(r);
```

This should threshold this image. However, it does not do so. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best would be to use [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833):

```
f(f<t)=0; % set all elements of f<t to 0
f(~(f==0))=1; % Set all elements where f is not 0 (i.e. the rest) to 1
```

`f<t` nicely produces a logical matrix adhering to the condition, but subsequently you do either `f=1` or `f=0`, meaning that you set the entirety of `f` to be a **scalar** (one or zero), which of course just plots a black or white square. Instead, use the logical matrix as indexing operation into the matrix itself, then assigning the desired value to each `true` entry, like above.

Also a `function` definition either goes in its own file, or on the bottom of the script. Thus either you save the function as `imgThreshold.m` and leave the rest for the script, or first call the script and place `function f = imgThreshold(img, t)` etc after the call to `imshow`