# Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have an array `StartMeasuring,` which is filled with 10 numbers. I would like to fill the matrix `Depth` with 10 arrays counting down to zero from the numbers in `StartMeasuring.`

```
StartMeasuring=randi([10 30],1,10);
lenDepth =len(StartMeasuring);
Depth=NaN(lenDepth,30);

for i=1:lenDepth
    Depth(i)=StartMeasuring(i):-1:0;
end
```

I tried to create a for loop and replacing a matrix with `NaN`'s, but I get the error :

```
Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.

Error in sd (line 53)
    Depth(i)=StartMeasuring(i):-1:0;
```

I don't understand why I get this error since both `Depth` and `StartMeasuring` are size 10.

Comment: `Depth` is actually of size 10x30, not 10 like `StartMeasuring`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StartMeasuring=randi([10 30],1,10);
lenDepth = length(StartMeasuring); % numel is preferred
Depth = NaN(lenDepth,31);

for ii = 1:lenDepth
    Depth(ii,1:StartMeasuring(ii)+1) = StartMeasuring(ii):-1:0;
end
```

Indexing with a singular number, like you did initially, gets, unsurprisingly, a single element of the matrix. Instead, index into the *row* as a single number, letting it fill all *columns* based on the expression. Read more about indexing in [this great post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833).

Also the size of `StartMeasuring(ii):-1:0` is random between 30 and 1, meaning that you have to store it based on its current length, which in your case (integers) is given by `StartMeasuring(ii)+1`.

Figure showing `imagesc(Depth)`:

[image]

---

Note that I changed several other things:

- `len` is Python, not MATLAB. Use `length`, or, preferably for 1D arrays `numel`
- spaces around the assignment operator `=` make for better readability
- [`i` and `j` are the imaginary unit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14790740/5211833) and it's customary to not use them as variable names in MATLAB.