# matlab transform logical index to range

Tags: matlab

Couldn't find a quick answer for this, it seems super simple but I don't get it. I want do the following transformation (for this example using my imaginary function `transform`):

```
a=[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0];
b=(-1:2); %rule to transform for every true value in [a], -1:2 should be true
transform(a,b) %should output [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0]

a=[0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0]; %another example
transform(a,b) %should output [0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0];
```

Is there an quick way of doing this transform, maybe using logical operators?

edit: I tried

```
a(find(a)'+(-1:2))=1 %requires matlab>2016 if I'm not mistaken, otherwise replace + sign with bsxfun(@plus,...)
```

but I'm looking for a possible function that does this without changing `a` and without using `find` (since using find kind of defeats the purpose of using logical matrices/indexing in the first place)

Comment: possible dup: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox you can use [`imdilate`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imdilate.html):

```
nh(max(abs([b(1),b(end)]))+1+b) = true;
result = imdilate(a, nh);
```

Answer (score 2):

I found an elegant oneliner that should solve your problem:

```matlab
b=(-1:2)
a(find(a) + b(:)) = 1;
```

Hope it helps!