# What mathematical function does reshape perform?

Tags: python, matlab, matrix, reshape

In both Python and MATLAB you can use a function called `reshape()` to change the dimensions of the matrix.

What operation is this in linear algebra, is this a change of basis, or a more simple matrix multiplication or is it neither of these?

Comment: Have you looked at the examples in the [`reshape`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) documentation (MATLAB)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This function has nothing to do with linear algebra, it is a simple indexing trick. Consider the following (I'll use [MATLAB syntax](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html), but in Python, especially using [NumPy/SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html), it'd function the same):

```matlab
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6]; % 2-by-3 matrix
B = reshape(A,3,2); % B is 3-by-2
B =
     1     5
     4     3
     2     6
```

So actually you have 6 indices in `A`: 1 to 6, in column-major order. When reshaping, the linear style is kept, just reordered. Linearly your elements are, in ascending order: `1 4 2 5 3 6`, which are stored in contiguous memory. A 'header' of sorts tells the program then how these contiguous elements are shaped. This is why a `reshape` is almost free: it only changes the header.

Linear algebra has nothing to do with this, this is just a numerical trick to make certain programming tasks easier.

For more information on how indexing in MATLAB works, I recommend [this great Q/A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833).

Under the hood MATLAB converts `A(2,2)` to `A(4)`, i.e. the fourth linear index, using [`sub2ind()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html), precisely because everything is stored as a linear vector. All reshaping does is to tell the header that element 3 is no longer at `A(1,2)`, but changed to `A(3,1)` because its appearance changed.

Comment: Any reference? That what you show is just simple transpose. I'm not sure if in more complicated reshape it will be the same.

Comment: @Karls just chuck this in MATLAB, the transpose of `A` would be `[1 4; 2 5; 3 6]`, which is a different matrix than the transposed one. Transposing changes the order of elements, hence it is more expensive than a simple reshape

Comment: Ok, right, it is not equivalent to transpose. I still think it may be more complicated than just a header. Do you have any reference which can support your explanation?

Comment: @Karls: The reference is the documentation to `reshape`, which Adriaan linked, as well as [this other documentation page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/array-indexing.html#MatrixIndexingExample-2).

Comment: You can create a really large array, and time how long it takes to do a reshape and how long it takes to do a transpose. You'll see that `reshape` is trivial, no data is copied, and that the transpose takes a non-trivial amount of time, it does copy data.

Answer (score 1):

**According to the python documentation** [1](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html),[2](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html), it just ravels the array (so makes t a linear 1-D vector. Then, using indexing, it is returned to new array of defined size. For example:

```matlab
start_array = 
[1,2,3,4;
5,6,7,8;
9,10,11,12]

i_a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] %implicit, not visible for user

result_array = 
[i_a(1), i_a(6), i_a(11); 
i_a(5), i_a(10), i_a(4); 
i_a(9), i_a(3), i_a(8); 
i_a(2), i_a(7), i_a(12)]
```

Comment: You now consider your elements to be row-major; they are not, instead they are stored (at least in MATLAB, which syntax you are using)  in column-major order.

Comment: The row- or -column order is irrelevant here, it only show the concept. I'm basing it on official Python SciPy documentation, in MATLAB it can be done other way.

Comment: under the hood, numpy arrays are like MATLABs, 1D, always. It just changes the way it translates 2D (in this case) indices into that 1D array, and how it displays them.

Comment: Quote from documentation `You can think of reshaping as first raveling the array [...] then inserting [...] using the same kind of index`. So if they are native stored linear, it sound like trivialization.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest matrix you can reshape is 2x2, but you'll get the idea.  (Sorry, StackOverflow won't let me insert images or LaTex, so, you'll need to suffer a little to read this.)

We start with `A=[[a,b],[c,d]]` and we want to reshape it into a 1x4 array: `[[a,b,c,d]]`.  You can do this algebraically:

```
[[1,0]] * A * [[1,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]] + 
[[1,0]] * A * [[0,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0]] + 
[[0,1]] * A * [[0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0]] + 
[[0,1]] * A * [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]
```

The `*` denotes matrix multiplication.

Every term is a product of conformable matrices: `1x2 * 2x2 * 2x4` which gives you a result of shape `1x4`.

The 1st term gives you `[[a,0,0,0]]`, the 2nd `[[0,b,0,0]]`, the 3rd `[[0,0,c,0]]` and the 4th `[[0,0,0,d]]`.

Generalizing this to arbitrary A of shape `nxm` shouldn't be too hard.  You will need `n*m` terms instead of 4, since your reshaped matrix will be `1x(n*m)`.  Each term will need to be conformable, so, you will need a matrix of shape `1xn` to hit A from the left, and a matrix of shape `mx(n*m)` to hit A from the right.

If you need to reshape an A of shape `nxm` to a shape `kxl`, where `k*l=n*m`, you will need to hit A from the left with `kxn` matrices and from the right with `mx(k*l)` matrices.