# Hierarchy between and / or in an if statement

Tags: matlab, if-statement

I have a file called `data`, within which there is a part `Data.ensemble` of which the first few lines look as following:

```
                Year Month Day Hour Min Temp
0   1635    1   2009    12  10  22  36  16.28
0   1635    2   2009    12  10  22  37  17.25
0   1635    3   2009    12  10  22  38  16.97
0   1635    4   2009    12  10  22  39  16.69
0   1635    5   2009    12  10  22  40  17.42
```

I want to extract the temperature in December on minute 0, 20, 30 and 40 every hour. I have trouble coding this. This is what I am trying:

```
Month = 12;
Minute = [0 20 30 40];

if Data.ensemble(:, 5) == Month & (Data.ensemble(:, 8) == (Minute(1) | Minute(2) | Minute(3) | Minute(4)))
    Temperature = Data.ensemble(:, 10)
end
```

This doesn't seem to create `Temperature`, and I expect it's just gonna copy the entire colomn, not just the temperature for the correct minutes. Moreover, I am not quite sure the brackets really use the right hierarchy between and / or. It has to always be december (12) and on of the minutes (0 or 20 or 30 or 40).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32379805/linear-indexing-logical-indexing-and-all-that):

```
%dummy data

x = datevec(now+[1:30]+170)

% x =
%
%   2019.0000     11.0000     30.0000     12.0000     56.0000     43.4885
%   2019.0000     12.0000      1.0000     12.0000     56.0000     43.4885
%   2019.0000     12.0000      2.0000     12.0000     56.0000     43.4885
%   2019.0000     12.0000      3.0000     12.0000     56.0000     43.4885
%   2019.0000     12.0000      4.0000     12.0000     56.0000     43.4885
%    ... 

%create a logical index to get each 10th,20th and 30th day of the month in december.
%we can use ismember to check several day at once.
index = ismember(x(:,3),[10,20,30]) & x(:,2) == 12
y     = x(index,:)

% y =
%
%   2019.000     12.000     10.000     12.000     59.000     13.826
%   2019.000     12.000     20.000     12.000     59.000     13.826
```

If you want to use an if else statement you need a for loop to check each row individually.

Comment: Aside from day vs minute, sounds better

Comment: It is just an example to understand the logic.

Comment: Agreed. You show ismember, which is what important here.

Answer (score 1):

You're close, but if you try to evaluate your logical conditions, you'll see it doesn't work:

```
>> Minute(1)|Minute(2)|Minute(3)|Minute(4)
ans = 1
```

And so (assuming I store your data in the variable `A`):

```
>> (A(:,8) == (Minute(1)|Minute(2)|Minute(3)|Minute(4)))
ans =

  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

Given that:

```
>> A(:,5) == Month
ans =

  1
  1
  1
  1
  1
```

We get:

```
>> A(:,5) == Month & (A(:,8)==(Minute(1)|Minute(2)|Minute(3)|Minute(4)))
ans =

  0
  0
  0
  0
  0
```

which means the condition is never true and `Temperature` never gets defined. The correct way to do this is (or I should say one of the ways to do this) is by using [logical indexing](https://uk.mathworks.com/company/newsletters/articles/matrix-indexing-in-matlab.html):

```
>> idx = ( A(:,8)==Minute(1)|A(:,8)==Minute(2)|A(:,8)==Minute(3)|A(:,8)==Minute(4)) & A(:,5) == Month

idx =

  0
  0
  0
  0
  1
```

You can then define your temperature as:

```
>> Temperature = A(idx,9)
Temperature =  17.420
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **logical indexing**:

```
tf = Data.ensemble(:,5) == Month & any(Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute, 2);
Temperature = Data.ensemble(tf,9)
```

Or **find**:

```
ind = find(Data.ensemble(:,5) == Month & any(Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute, 2));
Temperature = Data.ensemble(ind,9)
```

**Note:** `find` is a slower than logical indexing.

**Explanation:**

**`Data.ensemble(:,5) == Month`** returns a logical column vector with `1` where the condition is true and `0` for false. For your example the result will be:

```
5×1 logical array
   1
   1
   1
   1
   1
```

**`Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute`** returns a logical matrix where each column is for each element of `Minute`. For your example the result will be:

```
  5×4 logical array
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1
```

**`any(Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute, 2)`**: To get a single logical vector that is `1` for each row that has a `1` (= a minute condition was matched), we call `any` on the rows (the second dimension). For your example the result will be:

```
5×1 logical array
   0
   0
   0
   0
   1
```

Calling:

`any(Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute, 2)`

is shorter than:

```
Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute(1) | Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute(2) | Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute(3) | Data.ensemble(:,8) == Minute(4)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a misunderstanding of how [logical indexing](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/02/20/logical-indexing-multiple-conditions/) works in MATLAB, but aside from that, you got the right idea.

The expression `(Minute(1) | Minute(2) | Minute(3) | Minute(4))` will do [logical `or`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/or.html) on the scalar elements. Since they are all non-zero (and scalars), the result is always 1. Since your minute is rarely going to be 1, this is probably going to select nothing.

The expression `Data.ensemble(:, 5) == Month` creates a logical array with the same number of elements as there are rows in `Data.ensemble`. Some of the elements may be 0, if there is more data than what you show in the example. This expression likely gave you a warning, since the logical value of the resulting array is ambiguous:

1. You can set it to 1 if any element is 1
2. You can set it to 0 if any element is 0
3. You can set it to 1 if the array is simply non-empty
4. Any other criterion that makes sense in context ...

Even if final condition were to come out 1, the expression `Temperature = Data.ensemble(:, 10)` would just set `Temperature` to the entire 10th column.

You are looking instead to apply a corrected version of that `if` statement to each individual row of the data. The trick is to use a logical array to encode your condition, and then use that logical array as an index:

```
 month_is_12 = (Data.ensemble(:, 5) == Month);
 minute_is_good = ismember(Data.ensemble(:, 8), Minute);
```

[`ismember`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) will check each element of the 8th column against the `Minute` array to determine if it matches any of the elements. It's equivalent to doing

```
minute_is_good = ((Data.ensemble(:, 8) == Minute(1)) | (Data.ensemble(:, 8) == Minute(2)) | (Data.ensemble(:, 8) == Minute(3)) | (Data.ensemble(:, 8) == Minute(4)));
```

Not only does `ismember` look nicer, but it lets you modify the size of `Minute` without having to modify your actual code.

Now you don't need an `if` to get the data you want:

```
Temperature = Data.endemble(month_is_12 & minute_is_good);
```