# Create a structure in loop

Tags: matlab, loops, structure

I have several folders. In every folder is 1 file called Data. Every file has structures, one of those is Data.ensemble. From this structure I extract the temperature (column 9, see question [Hierarchy between and / or in an if statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56561706/hierarchy-between-and-or-in-an-if-statement/56563272#56563272)) . My problem now is within my loop, to extract and save this temperature in a structure every iteration. For example, if I have 10 folders and 10 files. I want

```
Temperature.1=[12 15 10...]
Temperature.2=[20 30 11...]
...
Temperature.10=[15 26 27...]
```

and these will all be different sizes. The extraction works fine, it is saving it that is a problem. I tried the following code with help from https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/304405-create-a-struct-iteratively

```
folders =struct2cell(dir(Pathfolders)); %Pathfolders is the path to the folders
NaamFolders=string(char(folders(1,:))); %make a list of all the foldernames
lenNF=length(NaamFolders);

for i = 1:lenNF
    Map=char(NaamFolders(i,1)); % Give me the name of the first , second, ... folder
    Pathfiles=[Path,'\',Map,'\','*_new.mat']; %Make the path to the files that end with _new.mat (in my case only 1)
    files =struct2cell(dir(Pathfiles)); %Select all files that end with _new.mat (in my case only 1)
    NaamFiles=char(files(1,:)); % Make a list of the names of all those files (in my case only 1)
    FilePath=[Path,'\',Map,'\',NaamFiles]; %create path to that 1 file
    Data=load(FilePath); %load that file
    [lenData,lenvariables]=size(Data.ensemble) % determine the size of the file structure called ensemble
    idx=NaamFolders{i} %Select the name you want to call your structure in the variable you want to create
    index = ismember(Data.ensemble(:,8),[10,20,30]) & Data.ensemble(:,5) == 12; %determine the index where  column 5 == 12 and column 8 == 10 or 20 or 30
    RightData   = Data.ensemble(index,:) % this the data where the previous comment is true
    Temperature.idx=RightData(:,9) % this line does not work. For every iteration, create a new structure within temperature that extracts column 9 from RightData.

end
```

It is the last line that does not work and gives the error

```
Unable to perform assignment because dot indexing is not supported for variables of this type.
Error in ExtractTrajectory (line 36)
    Temperature.idx=RightData(:,9)
```

Comment: I believe you need some parentheses, as in https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/generate-field-names-from-variables.html - so your line would have `Temperature.(idx) = `

Comment: @etmuse still the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Variable name should start always with a **letter**.
- ***space***, ***number*** , special caracters such as ***~, #, %***  are not allowed.

> Check `NaamFolders` format or print its format for us.

what you can do if it starts with number is just add a given letter to all NaamFolders list elements as follows

```
NaamFolders = strcat('z',NaamFolders)
```

---

## Struct field format requirement

---

**case 1:**  *starting with **letter***

```
>> isvarname("folder1")

ans =

  logical

   1
```

**can be used with dot assignment**

```
>> check.("folder1") = 5

check = 

  struct with fields:

    folder1: 5
```

---

**case 2:**  *starting with **number***

```
>> isvarname("1folder")

ans =

  logical

   0
```

**can't be used with dot assignment**

```
>> check.("1folder") = 5
Invalid field name: '1folder'.
```

---

**case 3:**  *starting with **space***

```
>> isvarname("    folder")

ans =

  logical

   0
```

**can't be used with dot assignment**

```
>> check.("    folder") = 5
Invalid field name: '    folder'.
```

---

**case 4:**  *starting with **special character***

```
>> isvarname("#folder")

ans =

  logical

   0
```

**can't be used with dot assignment**

```
>> check.("#folder") = 5
Invalid field name: '#folder'.
```

Comment: my variable name indeed started with a special character. My problem is solved now