# How to remove NaN from MATLAB tables?

Tags: matlab, matrix, nan, matlab-table

I am getting `NaN` values when I am evaluating a semantic segmentation network. How can I replace `NaN` with `0`?

```
metrics = 

  semanticSegmentationMetrics with properties:

              ConfusionMatrix: [9×9 table]
    NormalizedConfusionMatrix: [9×9 table]
               DataSetMetrics: [1×5 table]
                 ClassMetrics: [9×3 table]
                 ImageMetrics: [5×5 table]

 metrics.ClassMetrics

ans =

  9×3 table

                   Accuracy      IoU      MeanBFScore

                   ________    _______    ___________
    Fat                  0           0            0  
    Intestine          NaN           0          NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
A = rand(4);  % Get random matrix
A(A>0.9) = nan; % Set some points to NaN
A
A =
    0.0596    0.5216    0.7224       NaN
    0.6820    0.0967    0.1499    0.6490
    0.0424    0.8181    0.6596    0.8003
    0.0714    0.8175    0.5186    0.4538
A(isnan(A)) = 0  % Get NaN values, set to 0
A =
    0.0596    0.5216    0.7224         0
    0.6820    0.0967    0.1499    0.6490
    0.0424    0.8181    0.6596    0.8003
    0.0714    0.8175    0.5186    0.4538
```

You can do this using [`isnan`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html). This creates a logical mask which you [can use to index](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) back into your original, and can set all corresponding elements to the desired number (`0` in this case).

For `tables` [`ismissing`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismissing.html) seems to be a viable alternative to `isnan`; syntax is exactly the same (`A(ismissing(A)) = 0`).

Comment: Hi Adriaan, How can i do in my case?

Comment: @Sohail like this, exactly. Since you don't show how you create your `semanticSegmentationMetrics` or whatever it is, I cannot tell you in more detail. Just use `isnan()` on whatever that is.