# Multidimensional array : Split and put back together

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, split, reshape

I am trying to turn a 3 dimensional array  "upside-down" as:
[image]

I have tried the `inverse` function, but if we look at the inverse operation in mathematical terms, it gives us another result. I need to turn without changing the data in the array. How to do that?

To split the 3-dimensional array (`A x B x C`) into A-sub-array (2d, `B x C`) I have used `squeeze`: `k=squeeze(array(n,:,:))`. Now I have a 2-dimensional array of size `B x C`. How to put it back together (in 3 dimensional array)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`permute()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html) to change the order of dimensions, which can be used as a multidimensional transpose.

Putting 2D matrices into a 3D one then is a simple indexing operation. Read more in indexing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833).

```
A = rand(10,10,10);
B = permute(A, [ 3 2 1 ]);  % Permute he order of dimensions

mat1 = rand(10,10);
mat2 = rand(10,10);
mat_both(:,:,2) = mat2; % Stack 2D matrices along the third dimension
mat_both(:,:,1) = mat1;

mat_both = cat(3,mat1, mat2);  % Stacks along the third dimension in a faster way
```