# Dividing a matrix into two parts

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, matrix, dataset

I am trying to classify my dataset. To do this, I will use the 4th column of my dataset. If the 4th column of the dataset is equal to 1, that row will added in new matrix called `Q1`. If the 4th column of the dataset is equal to 2, that row will be added to matrix `Q2`.

My code:

```matlab
i = input('Enter a start row: ');
j = input('Enter a end row: ');
search = importfiledataset('search-queries-features.csv',i,j);
[n, p] = size(search);

if j>n
   disp('Please enter a smaller number!');
end

for s = i:j
    class_id = search(s,4);
    if class_id == 1 
       Q1 = search(s,1:4)        
    elseif class_id ==2  
       Q2 = search(s,1:4)
    end
end
```

This calculates the `Q1` and `Q2` matrices, but they all are 1x4 and when it gives new `Q1` the old one is deleted. I need to add new row and make it 2x4 if conditions are true. I need to expand my `Q1` matrix.

Briefly I am trying to divide my dataset into two parts using `for` loops and `if` statements.

Dataset:

[image]

I need outcome like:

```
Q1 = [30  64  1  1
      30  62  3  1
      30  65  0  1
      31  59  2  1
      31  65  4  1
      33  58 10  1
      33  60  0  1
      34  58 30  1
      34  60  1  1 
      34  61 10  1]

Q2 = [34 59 0 2
      34 66 9 2]
```

How can I prevent my code from deleting previous rows of `Q1` and `Q2` and obtain the entire matrices?

Comment: Actually main problem is not if statement the problem is creating arrays (Q1,Q2)

Comment: You are overwriting `Q1` and `Q2` in each iteration. Why do you want to use loops and if statements? If you have to then preallocate `Q1` and `Q2` and then replace their rows. At the end remove the unused rows.  Why don't you use simple logical indexing as suggested by @Adriaan?

Comment: I had issues when I am editing it that's why I add new post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem in your calculation is that you *overwrite* `Q1` and `Q2` each loop iteration. Best solution: get rid of the loops and use logical indexing.

You can use [logical indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) to quickly determine where a column is equal to `1` or `2`:

```
search = [
  30 64 1 1 
  30 62 3 1
  30 65 0 1
  31 59 2 1
  31 65 4 1
  33 58 10 1
  33 60 0 1
  34 59 0 2
  34 66 9 2
  34 58 30 1
  34 60 1 1 
  34 61 10 1
];
Q1 = search(search(:,4)==1,:)  % == compares each entry in the fourth column to 1

Q2 = search(search(:,4)==2,:)

Q1 =
    30    64     1     1
    30    62     3     1
    30    65     0     1
    31    59     2     1
    31    65     4     1
    33    58    10     1
    33    60     0     1
    34    58    30     1
    34    60     1     1
    34    61    10     1
Q2 =
    34    59     0     2
    34    66     9     2
```

---

### Warning: Slow solution!

If you are hell bent on using loops, make sure to not overwrite your variables. Either extend them each iteration (which is very, very slow):

```
Q1=[];
Q2=[];

for ii = 1:size(search,1) % loop over all rows
   if search(ii,4)==1
       Q1 = [Q1;search(ii,:)];
   end
   if search(ii,4)==2
       Q2 = [Q2;search(ii,:)];
   end
end
```

MATLAB will put orange wiggles beneath `Q1` and `Q2`, because it's a bad idea to grow arrays in-place. Alternatively, you can preallocate them as large as `search` and strip off the excess:

```
Q1 = zeros(size(search)); % Initialise to be as large as search
Q2 = zeros(size(search));

Q1kk = 1; % Intialiase counters
Q2kk = 1;

for ii = 1:size(search,1) % loop over all rows
   if search(ii,4)==1
       Q1(Q1kk,:) = search(ii,:); % store
       Q1kk = Q1kk + 1; % Increase row counter
   end
   if search(ii,4)==2
       Q2(Q2kk,:) = search(ii,:);
       Q2kk = Q2kk + 1;
   end
end

Q1 = Q1(1:Q1kk-1,:); % strip off excess rows
Q2 = Q2(1:Q2kk-1,:);
```

Comment: Actually I did not know Q2 = search(search(:,4)==2,:)  I am new on Matlab but it works perfectly and very easy to understand solution thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `accumarray`, if `Q` is your original matrix:

```
Q = accumarray(Q(:,4),1:size(Q,1),[],@(x){Q(x,:)});
```

You can access the result with `Q{1}` (for class_id = 1), `Q{2}` (for class_id = 2) and so on...