# How can we add a vector to a single column of a matrix?

Tags: arrays, matrix, vector, octave, addition

I want to add a vector to just a single column of a matrix.

For example:

```
a = zeros(5,5);
b = ones(5,1);
```

I want to add such `b` only to the second column of a such that the resultant `a` is

```
a= [ 0 1 0 0 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;
     0 1 0 0 0;]
```

How can I do this? I have tried doing `a+b` but it adds one to all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a(:,2) = a(:,2)+b` does this. Specifically, you index all rows, `:`, of the second column, `2`, of `a`, and add the vector `b` to that. Read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32379805/5211833) for details on various indexing methods.

[rahnema1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324707/how-can-we-add-a-vector-to-a-single-column-of-a-matrix/59325088?noredirect=1#comment104850715_59325088) mentioned that Python-like syntax of adding to or subtracting from an argument does not require that argument to be repeated. You can thus do:

```
a:(,2) += b
```

Comment: Also in Octave `a(:,2) += b;` is valid .